# Что делать с вопросами в стиле "скажите что почитать"?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика, учебные-материалы

В справке SO на странице "What topics can I ask about here?" есть следующее:

> ...Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:...
>
> ...Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource...

На этом подсайте такого текста нет в соответствующей странице справки. И подобные вопросы встречаются по нескольку штук на странице.

Мне кажется такие вопросы можно выяснить с помощью гугла. Кроме того советы по выбору книг и других ресурсов для обучения слишком субъективные.

Стоит такие вопросы рекомендовать к удалению?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Мне кажется, не стоит относиться к таким вопросам слишком плохо — по крайней мере на начальном этапе. Такие вопросы интересуют многих, иначе они бы не задавались так много раз.

С другой стороны, на подобные вопросы было много раз отвечено.

Моё предложение:

1. Когда приходит запрос на книги по теме X, проверить, что у нас ещё нет канонического ответа на этот вопрос. Если есть, закрыть как дубликат.
2. Если канонического ответа нет, нужно собрать ответ(ы) из старых вопросов, или дописать свои. Может быть, администрации стоит для этого объявить конкурс.
3. Если в результате пункта 2 получен канонический ответ, присвоить вопросу специальную метку ([книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8)?), и впредь давать ссылки на него. Уточнения и дополнения также давать лишь в каноническом вопросе (в том же или новом ответе).
4. После этого, возможно, закрыть старые вопросы как дубликаты каноническому.

Comment: Поддерживаю, хотя думаю формальных конкурсов не надо. Может быть просто подсказать в комментариях к таким вопросам, чтобы Общие вопросы использовались, чтобы голосование по каждой книге/набору можно было проводить.

Comment: @jfs: Я имел в виду bounty, собственно.

Comment: @VladD Как администрация может объявить конкурс, если суть конкурса в передаче X репутации от пользователя A пользователю B?

Comment: @Athari: Окей, согласен выступать донором.

Comment: Дополнение 1. Ссылки на "канонические" ответы будут кстати в описании соответствующих меток. Дополнение 2. "Канонический" ответ о книгах можно делать общим. Например, у вопрос будет "общий" ответ, помеченный как решение, и множество "авторских" ответов, дополняющих или высказывающих личные точки зрения.

Answer (score 16):

Меня, конечно, сейчас заминусуют в пол, но я всё-таки выскажусь. Есть несколько проблем с вопросами "Что почитать?":

1. Если тема хоть сколь-нибудь популярна, то **выбор невероятно широк**, особенно если вопрос про язык программирования или популярную платформу. В результате каждый юзер постит одну-две книжки, которые он сам прочитал. Ни сравнения, ни адекватной оценки (ни от юзера, ни голосами), как правило, не дождёшься. Нормальное обсуждение в комментариях невозможно.
2. Если вопрос касается современных вещей (а для программирования это почти всегда так), то **списки невероятно быстро устаревают**. Конечно, есть бессмертная классика, но ей сыт не будешь. Чтобы поддерживать список актуальным, нужно много усилий, а этим никто заниматься не будет (за редактирование репу не дают).

В результате вопрос про книги собирает неполный список книжек, прочитанных парой юзеров, и ещё несколько юзеров от балды раскидывает плюсики ответам. Через год-два этот список, даже если он более-менее адекватный и актуальный, можно выбрасывать.

Единственный надёжный способ получить актуальный список — это задать вопрос заново.

На традиционном форуме, который не построен вокруг формата QA, вопрос про литературу будет гораздо более уместен. Участники могут перечислить их любимые книги, обсудить достоинства и недостатки и т.п.

Если кто-то хочет разубедить меня, то пусть покажет мне канонические ответы про техническую литературу по топ-10 (а лучше топ-20) самых популярных языков на сайте. Эти ответы должны быть полными и акутальными. Разрешаю даже написать все 10 ответов самостоятельно. Тогда — поверю.

Можно долго рассуждать про полезность таких списков, но в конечном счёте они приводят к протухшей информации, которая высоко ранжируется в гугле, мешая найти реально актуальную информацию. Может, это и привлечёт кого-то на сайт, но уйдут они разочарованными, потому что информация окажется для них бесполезной.

Comment: Ладно вам, у нас тут не минусуют. :-) Выбор и правда широк, но если уж есть канонический вопрос, можно написать новый ответ. Или обновить старый. Вот пример вопроса, который работает таким образом: [en.SO: Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/81656/276994).

Comment: @VladD У меня баджик "Давление общества / Peer pressure" за предложение избавиться от тега "нытье", поэтому не надо рассказывать, что не минусуют. Меня — минусуют. :) / Приведённый вами пример как раз не "дайте почитать", а вполне себе формальный список стандартов: список задокументирован на многих сайтах, в том числе на официальных; вопрос "включать или не включать" не возникает. Ну и учитывая умопомрачительную скорость развития C++, обновлять его часто не требуется. :) Ссылки на Амазон, конечно, попахивают, но не критично.

Comment: Тэг «нытьё»? Ну вы даёте, вы бы ещё в Индии предложили упразднить культ священной коровы :-)

Comment: Ну, пример, конечно, не полностью аналогичный. Но мне кажется, поддерживать хороший список литературы нам всё равно нужно, как reference-источнику данных. Вот вам ещё один пример: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/276994).

Comment: @VladD Ну да, редкий случай "community lock", когда выпиливаются все ответы, собираются в один, и кроме редактирования этого ответа больше ничего делать нельзя. Но у нас-то такое есть?

Comment: Технически возможно, раз возможно на en.SO. Думаю, вопрос лишь в нашем желании.

Comment: @VladD Что называется, поверю, когда увижу. Для поддержания подобных статей в актуальном состоянии нужна критическая масса помешанных на вики. Так как я чукча (который писатель, а не читатель), то сам ничего порекомендовать не могу.

Comment: А, вы в этом смысле! Ну, даже если текст будет отставать от реальности, в него будут добавляться специфические для русскоязычного читателя данные (хорошие переводы? «наши» авторы?), так что всё равно статья будет более-менее релевантной и лучше, чем постоянная отсылка в Гугл.

Answer (score 3):

Я на такой вопрос (в прошлом) написал авторов, их книги плюс ссылки на хорошие сайты (для бесплатного изучения) по теме. Ну и все остальные источники, которыми пользовался и (или) пользуюсь сам. И, после того как подробно аргументировал каждую книгу и ссылку, получил "лучший ответ" от благодарного человека.

Answer (score 3):

> Мне кажется такие вопросы можно выяснить с помощью гугла.

Любые вопросы можно выяснить при помощи гугла => stackoverflow нужно закрыть.

> Кроме того советы по выбору книг и других ресурсов для обучения
>   слишком субъективные.

Разве не в этом состоит смысл stackoverflow? Тут каждый ответ субъективен. В противном случае нужно слить все аккаунты в один мега-аккаунт и отвечать им на все вопросы во всех категориях бесконечно правя один и тот же ответ (да, это Википедия).

Comment: Не согласен с обоими выводами. 1. Гугл очень на многие проблемы первыми строками отправляет в SO и, нередко, остальные варианты это беспредметный флуд на форумах или вообще материалы не по теме. 2. Не в этом. Здесь помогают решить конкретные проблемы. Если ответ решает проблему - это хороший ответ. Если нет критериев "решенности" проблемы - то ответы превращаются в спор: "что вкуснее, колбаса или торт?"

Comment: 1. Путаете возможность и удобство. 2. А причём здесь качество ответа? Все 100% ответов субъективны вне зависимости от их качества.

Comment: 1. Не путаю. Если из приведенной ситуации убираем SO - теряем ответ. 2. Это главный фактор успеха SO. Вопрос типа 2 + 2 - позволяет дать однозначный ответ. Вопрос "подскажите что почитать" - повод для наполнения сайта информационным мусором (особенно если такие вопросы множатся)

Comment: @tutankhamun, для Вас -- мусор, для кого-то другого -- "жемчуг". Чем Ваше мнение лучше?

Answer (score 3):

Сложно определить правильный поступок, так как неправильно сформулирована идея того, кто задаёт вопрос. К примеру, если вопрос «Что почитать?» означает, что вопрос про книги, то предлагаю перенаправлять на вопросы [такого рода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1). А сам вопрос закрыть как «дубликат».