# Вопросы про софт: "что лучше"

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика

Можно ли здесь задавать вопросы и обсуждать:

- IDE, VCS
- Библиотеки?

Речь идет о вопросах "какой %s лучше" / "что лучше юзать для %s"

Comment: Можно. Посмотрите количество вопросов по IDEA, git, boost.

Comment: @Etki а вопросы про то, какой софт лучше? Никто не будет вонять про "SO не список"?

Comment: @Smith будут. Но если вы сформируете формальный список требований, то вам и выдадут формальные ответы.

Comment: @Etki все равно будет не один ответ, как я понимаю это и есть претензия к таким вопросам.

Comment: Если будет нормально сформулированый вопрос (не просто просьба подсказать лучшее), то будут нормальные ответы.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, обратите внимание на [этот, например, вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435684/178576). формально он о выборе, а фактически — **очень далёк** от «посоветуйте мне что-нибудь эдакое».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin короче. Если я задам вопрос про "какую иде для %s" выбрать с обсуждением плюсов и минусов в традициях softwaretechs - его не закроют?

Comment: @Etki поясни мне, чем "нормально сформулированый вопрос" отличается от просьбы подсказать лучшее и какие критерии  "нормально сформулированого вопроса" про софт?

Comment: @SmitJohnth: очень много вопросов имеют много правильных ответов. Например, вопросы типа «как на языке X сделать Y со строкой Z». И никто не против.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, если вопрос будет звучать так, как вы написали: «какую ide выбрать для %s?» (где «%s» — любой язык программирования) — это, на мой взгляд, однозначный *offtopic*.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Но вопросы в стиле какой самый лучший X и их бурное обсуждение в каментах — это неформат, и вероятно никогда не будет форматом. За такими обсуждениями добро пожаловать в чат (в котором три с половиной участника), он для того и создан. Здесь не обсуждают вклад, а ставят плюс/минус, так работает весь stackoverflow. Даже Хэшкод, который был гораздо ближе к желаемой вами модели, не поддержал бы обсуждение, которое вы хотите.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Если вы зададите чёткие критерии, больше шансов, что вопрос «взлетит». Чем форматнее вопрос, тем легче ему вписаться в формат :-)

Comment: "Я использую %IDE%, она прекрасна функциями X, Y, Z, но страшно тормозит при W. Есть ли какие-то аналоги с полным или частичным сохранением функций X-Y-Z, которые будут нормально работать в  случае W?"

Comment: @VladD для 3,5 участников есть сайты попроще. Нет, вопрос, например, какие есть ide для питона с плюсами и минусами.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: А почему бы не спросить в тематическом чате Питонистов? У нас, правда, его нету, но наверняка есть на en.SO.

Comment: @VladD речь идет именно у вас и в виде вопроса, так спросить можно много у кого. У питонистов, кстати, спрашивать не хочу, ибо фанатики.

Comment: *спрашивать не хочу, ибо фанатики* — звучит похоже: «как лучше всего отправлять ритуалы в секте икс? у членов секты спрашивать не хочу, ибо фанатики.»

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Ну, я настолько не-Питонист, что свою единственную строчку на Питоне написал в каком-то ответе на StackOverflow, поэтому могу выбирать только из одного варианта: онлайн-редактор ответов тут.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в частности, на вопрос "X под виндой" реально получить ответ "а лучше перейти на линупс". Да, питон - вендовраждебное говно, но вопрос так не стоит.

Comment: @SmitJohnth вы всегда себя так агрессивно ведёте? К чему такие резкие комментарии? Вопрос "Какую IDE/библиотеку лучше использовать для Х?" - это вопрос не по теме сайта. Вопрос "Как в IDE/библиотеке X сделать конкретное У?" имеет шансы на успех, особенно если вы уважаете чужое время, предварительно попытались решить проблему самостоятельно и описали неудачную попытку в вопросе.

Comment: @Regent По отношению к кому я себя агрессивно веду? Мы же здесь за этот сайт говорим? Захотелось вам обсудить другие ресурсы - ок, обсудили. "Какую IDE/библиотеку лучше использовать для Х?" - да, именно это я и имел в виду, т.е. рекомендация софта, а не решения конкретной проблемы, с этого стоило бы и начать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не все питонисты - фанатики.

Answer (score 6):

Нельзя. А если можно, то пусть будет нельзя - тут рядом [подходящая тема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1120/) была :)

Comment: Адвокат, блин ) Плюс за блестящую аргументацию!

Comment: Ничем не хуже другого ответа по сути ;-)

Comment: добавил ссылки для усиления абсурда. ))

Comment: Мне больше без ссылок нравилось, но пусть будет, если другой автор не против )

Answer (score 2):

Можно. А если нельзя, то пусть будет можно - тут рядом [подходящая тема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/) была :)