# Вопросы — списки инструментария разработки

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика, правила

У нас уже есть вопросы, хранящие списки литературы. ([Что делать с вопросами в стиле "скажите что почитать"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/181472))  Договорились о том, что на один язык будет создаваться и поддерживаться силами сообщества один вопрос.

**Вопрос: рационально ли будет поддерживать аналогичные списки для инструментов разработки?**

Вызвано вот этим вопросом: [Среда разработки для C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/12570/181472)

Пример хорошего вопроса по той же теме: [IDE для C и C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3592/181472)

Кстати, похоже, что это уже обсуждалось: [Вопросы про софт: "что лучше"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/797/181472)

Вопросы о настройке этих инструментов уже точно являются вопросами по теме. Вопросы по выбору инструментов все равно задаются. Не стоит ли сделать аналогичные ответы и в них предоставить по возможности полную информацию?

- [Аргументы «за»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1144/181472)
- [Аргументы «против»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1162/181472)
- [Создавать, но в описаниях меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1190/181472)

Comment: Кстати, а почему мы ограничиваемся только списками "инструментария разработки"? Чем плохи все остальные списки.. Надо бы общее решение.

Comment: @KromStern: предложил общее решение, посмотрите. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1190/181472

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Эти списки нужно хранить в описаниях меток.

И вот почему:

- Метка доступна из любого вопроса по этой метке (как ни удивительно).
- Даже без вопроса она находится быстро.
- Содержимое описания метки лучше защищено от вандализма
- Строго задан формат одного блока текста, а не многих разрозненных ответов.
- Голосовать нельзя (и не о чем спорить)
- Не приносит баджей, репутации и прочего, то есть не провоцирует плодить такие списки из тщеславия.
- Проверено на практике как на En.SO, так и у нас (см. [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [регулярные-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f), [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql))

#### Там же должны быть и все остальные списки:

См. вопрос [Как правильно составлять описание метки (tag wiki)? Что туда включать?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/527/181472)

- Ссылки на внешнюю документацию (в смысле reference docs; например то, что выдает команда man subject).
- Ссылки на интерактивные учебники (tutorials), шпаргалки (cheatsheets).
- Список рекомендуемых книг (в том числе для разных уровней подготовки).
- Инструментарий (IDE и прочее)
- Ссылка на чат по теме метки (для нас пока почти не актуально)

#### Любые списки чего угодно в вопросах нужно удалять.

Comment: Гугл и прочие поисковики выдают ссылки только на вопросы-ответы на SO. И никогда на описание меток (по-моему). То есть через поисковик напрямую не выйдешь на такой список в описании метки. В итоге список может быть никогда не найден ищущим.

Answer (score 1):

Я голосую **«За»** такие вопросы.

Это вопросы по базовым знаниями.

**Аргументы за:**

- Лучше один хороший вопрос и ответ, чем много плохих, которые регулярно появляются и закрываются
- Эксперимент с книгами принес хорошие результаты
- Эти вопросы будут популярны в поисковой выдаче. Их существование оправдывает уже даже шанс того, что пользователи придут на них, а потом почитают что-нибудь более полезное, да и вообще станут активными участниками сайта. Многие впервые находят SO именно через поиск по конкретному вопросу.

**Условия публикации таких вопросов:**

- Их следует задать однажды, а возможность вносить изменения предоставить только опытным участникам, которые не будут устраивать «священные войны».
- Такие вопросы следует отмечать «общими». (Это автоматически делает «общими» все настоящие и будущие ответы)
- Предлагаемый формат: оглавление в вопросе, про каждый инструмент один ответ с подробными инструкциями по установке и обзором области применения.

Саму проблему споров можно избежать за счет того, что не оценивать среды разработки, а лишь публиковать список. В конечном счете, оценка «лучше» — субъективна и зависит от контекста.

С большой вероятностью, никаких споров между конкурентами не будет.

Comment: Я бы дополнил требованием о том, что вопрос и ответы обязательно должны быть общими. Этот вопрос непременно будет собирать просмотры и голоса, но эти голоса — за качества определенного инструмента, а не за знания и вклад участника.

Comment: Формат: оглавление в вопросе, про каждый инструмент один ответ с подробными инструкциями по установке и обзором применимости (если необходимо).

Comment: Обновил ответ согласно вашим замечанием, и сделал общим.

Comment: отлично! Я правильно понимаю, что на общий вопрос можно давать только общие ответы?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 0):

Я голосую **против**

- на поддержание ответа в актуальном состоянии требуется время.
- провокация споров о том, какая среда лучше.
- необходимо следить за объективностью описания конкурирующих инструментов
- сложно охватить весь список.
- длинные списки инструментов с субьективными оценками не решают, а, наоборот, обостряют проблему выбора для новичков.
- выбор очень сильно зависит от платформы. на Win ответ "Visual Studio или что-то от JetBrains" будет заплюсован с большим отрывом, что сводит на нет саму идею таких списков.
- аргументы из https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/165/177188.

Каждому ресурсу свое. Туториалам - туториалы, каталогам - каталоги, вопросникам - вопросы. Место таким спискам на Википедии (тем более что там они уже есть в большом количестве ([пример](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8))) и **в вики меток**.

*P.S. Ответ дан на правах "адвоката дьявола"*.

Comment: Небольшое дополнение от лица коллегии адвокатов дьявола ))

Comment: Тогда пусть будет "общим"

Comment: @KromStern подлил еще немного дегтя

Comment: @PashaPash: написал отдельный ответ с привкусом вашего дегтя.

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо

Comment: @PashaPash: я вроде бы и про книги когда-то возражал против вопросов-списков, но меня убедили, что решение уже принято и работает. Не могу найти, где это обсуждалось.