# Предлагаю закрыть или даже удалить списки IDE

Tags: предложение, тематика

Предлагаю закрыть или даже удалить вот эти вопросы (и аналогичные им):

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474754
- [Простой IDE для JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/204262)
- [Среда программирования для JavaScript. Что использовать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/151154)
- [IDE для C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/103108)
- [IDE для написания Android приложений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/13631)
- [IDE для C и C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3592)
- [IDE для Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464)

Списки IDE отлично гуглятся за 5 сек и даже представлены на википедии: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments

Причем на вики, списки сделаны в виде таблиц, с указанием различных фич и их поддержкой IDE - куда лучше чем это можно было бы сделать здесь.

Если уж совсем необходимо, то можно это **перенести в описание соответствующих меток**.

---

Забыл, оказывается тема уже обсуждалась ранее, ознакомиться можно здесь:
[Вопросы — списки инструментария разработки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На полноценный список там тянут

- [IDE для C и C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3592/ide-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-c-%D0%B8-c)
- [IDE для Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464/ide-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-python)

Их стоит перенести.

Все остальное - просто древние вопросы "посоветуйте" с парой ответов "а мне вот нравится IDE ZZZ".

Comment: если некоторые переносить а остальные нет возникает разумный вопрос: *Что за дискриминация по среде разработки*. лучше уж тогда поступить [так](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1190/17927)

Comment: @Bald56rus именно это я и предложил - перенести списки в метки. готовых юзабельных списков я вижу всего два.

Comment: ааа, имелось ввиду перенести в описание метки, тогда согласен

Answer (score 2):

Отчасти согласен с @KromStern, но вынужден таки заметить, что SO не просто место где получают ответы на вопросы по программированию, но также и место для обмена опытом.

Википедия не дает ответа на вопрос какая IDE лучше/подходит для того то и того то. Википедия лишь фиксирует голый факт.

Согласен, что тупые списки не нужны. Но вопросы, где люди делятся своим личным опытом использования различных IDE совсем нелишние.

Простой пример: я вот лично если завтра решу что-нибудь сбацать под LISP куда я полезу? В Википедию? Отнюдь - я полезу на SO и почитаю мнение опытных людей о том или ином IDE под LISP - например [типа такого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042601/common-lisp-ide-for-c-sharp-developer)

Comment: Дело в том, что подобные вопросы быстро превращаются в опросники, где каждый спешит вставить свои пять копеек на тему "а вот вы еще эту IDE забыли!"

Comment: Согласен. Но такие вопросы уже содержат критерии, и становятся конкретными.

Answer (score 2):

**Я против.**

Данный ресурс можно представить как "хорошо гуглящийся FAQ". То есть, `вопрос -> ответ+несколько` вариантов. Списки IDE тут уже не подойдут. Это ведь даже не вопрос, это заранее подготовленная статья с комментами в виде мнений.

*Таким вещам место на хабре. В крайнем случае, если тут сделают раздел гайдов/статей.*

Comment: Уточните, вы против чего конкретно и что предлагаете?

Comment: "Списки IDE тут уже не подойдут." - другими словами, SO сайт вопросов/ответов, причем вопросов с КОНКРЕТНОЙ проблемой и КОНКРЕТНЫМ решением/ями. А списки IDE под этот формат не подходит. А предлагаю я, или придерживаться уже созданных стандартов, или создать " раздел гайдов и статей"(как я уже написал). Иначе это выглядит как автомобиль поставленный на рельсы.

Answer (score 1):

И снова я за то, чтобы оставить старые вопросы в покое.

Comment: Тогда уж закрыть хотя бы.

Comment: Мы из SO вроде как хранилище знаний хотим сделать, поэтому хорошо бы и старые вопросы привести в порядок.

Comment: Первый вопрос из списка задан 13 часов назад. И он отличный индикатор, что некоторые воспринимают старые вопросы пример для подражания, вне зависимости от их качества. Решение по спискам на мете? Какая ещё мета?

Comment: Больше скажу - посмотрите похожие вопросы (списки справа) - они постоянно всплывают и/или задаются вновь

Comment: Я согласен, но только если для разработки на JS вы возьмете себе лучший IDE, по мнению сообщества - [Visual Web Developer 2010 Express](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/204306/177221). потому что "оставить в покое" равнозначно "советовать именно этот IDE всем новичкам".

Answer (score 1):

Все эти вопросы имеют большое число просмотров. Значит спрос есть. И вопросы надо переработать также как и вопросы по литературе: один список-эталон и закрыть все остальные как дубликаты.

Перенос же в описание меток, как я понимаю, нахождение этой инфы из гугла/яндекса сильно снизит. А это - прямой вред сайту и всем русскоговорящим кодерам.

Comment: А у рутрекера еще больше просмотров. Давайте сюда торренты добавим? У сайта есть своя ниша и цель (сборник профессиональных вопросов и ответов), а не просто - обслуживание наибольшего числа просмотров ;-)

Comment: @KromStern, вопросы про IDE непосредственно относятся к программированию... Мне такие вопросы нужны и интересны (и не только мне, согласно просмотрам). К сожалению, когда возникают такие вопросы приходится ходить в чат и там спрашивать. По мне так это не оч. удобно.

Comment: Делайте проще - идите на вики - там отличные беспристрастные таблицы! (см. ссылку в вопросе)

Comment: @KromStern, я согласен вот с этим ответом (http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2061/17609) - на вики я пойду не в первую очередь, я на автомате буду искать тут, на SO. Мне ж не беспристрастны список нужен - мне конкретный опыт программистов нужен)

Comment: @KromStern Подскажите, чем список IDE отличается от списка литературы?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky тем что список IDE уже есть на вики, с таблицей фич. Списков литературы на вики почему-то нет (кстати почему?). Если бы были - то и списки литературы я бы предложил сократить. Я сейчас не вижу миссии SO в том, чтобы стать "единственным и полным справочников программиста по всем проблемам, узким и широким". SO это движок и набор сайтов по вопросам предполагающим **единственный верный ответ**. Хотелось бы, конечно, чтобы и опросники в этот формат вошли, но, к сожалению, они не входят.

Comment: _единственный верный ответ_ – не соглашусь. Кстати, этот вопрос обсуждался не раз. Однозначно верный (или объективно верный) ответ, может быть и не один. Объективность говорит о том, что любой человек может проверить решение. Более того, модель Stack Overflow содержит вики-составляющую, которая выражается не просто в улучшении одного ответа, но и созданию из нескольких ответов одного, с добавлением своей экспертизы. Как мне кажется, в большинстве случаев _не бывает единственного верного ответа_.

Comment: _единственным и полным справочников программиста по всем проблемам, узким и широким_ – соглашусь. Stack Overflow призван сделать интернет лучшим местом для получения ответа на технический вопрос. Если проблему можно сформировать в качестве вопроса, на которую можно дать объективно верный ответ, то такому вопросу есть место на сайте. Подчеркну, я согласен с вами, что Stack Overflow не должен становиться чем-то большим чем база прикладных решений (как минимум, без документации).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky в текущем виде, я от таких списков вижу больше вреда, чем пользы. Литература и IDE свалены в одну кучу, без описания, без оценок, без ничего. Какая от этого польза и чем она больше чем от книжной полки в онлайн магазине?

Comment: @KromStern Пожалуйста, опишите по возможности как можно более детально ваши рекомендации по улучшению! Уверен, вместе мы сможем сделать эти безусловно востребованные знания полезными.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky *Однозначно верный (или объективно верный) ответ* согласен с более широкой трактовкой )

Comment: @KromStern, в нынешнем виде да, но можно ответы улучшить и сделать хороший общий ответ на все подобные вопросы как в случае с литературой. То, что в данный момент до этого руки у сообщества не дошли - не повод удалять вопросы) Тем более, что мне теперь нельзя удалённые посты смотреть из-за недавней люстрации((( И т.к. просмотров у вопросов много, то, даже с учётом их некоторой оффтопичности, их можно рассматривать (после приведения в надлежащий вид) как способ увеличения посещаемости.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вставлю свои пять копеек: я за список IDE, но я против того что есть на текущий момент. Вот если бы привести в порядок, например утвердить следующие правила/рекомендации: Название, условия использования, *плюшки*(ну например автодополнение) ну и т.п

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky думал над этим. Проблема в том что концентрированный список ни о чем не говорит (дай любому из нас список литературы по Blender из 40 книг, пользы 0). Надо как-то их рейтинговать, чтобы "Макконел" был сверху, а "Маринина" снизу. Это решается вариантом "1 ответ = 1 книга", но это занимает слишком много места по высоте - никто дальше 1 десятка проматывать не станет. Вот если бы ответы можно было сворачивать ... и по умолчанию они были свернуты, и только голоса, название и какая-то еще критическая инфа была видна - вот это был бы имхо идеал.

Comment: @KromStern Было бы здорово, если бы вынесли проблему и ваш вариант решения в отдельную публикацию, чтобы все сообщество могло принять участие в дискуссии.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не вижу в этом смысла, т.к. перекраивать движок никто не будет.

Comment: @KromStern, я лично не знаю как, но спойлеру в ответах видел. это можно как-то сделать в разметке вопросов/ответов.

Comment: @KromStern ок, вот в чем проблема со списками, актуальностью и голосованием: [IDE для JS](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/204262/). Наверху висит Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, который больше не Web Developer, не 2010, не Express, и который и тогда и сейчас был ужасным IDE для JS - в нем даже допечатка не работала для jquery.

Comment: @KromStern и сколько еще девелоперов уйдет в отмеченный зеленым ответ про недо-иде? отметку снять нельзя, 10 голосов против собрать - нереально, все жалеют еденички. И вызвана эта проблема исключительно спецификой **устаревания** списков. А не тем, что Бармалей тогда плохо ответил.

Comment: @PashaPash если это оформить в виде отдельного поста, то может 10 и наберется.