# Вопрос несправедливо отмечен как дубликат

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, учебные-материалы

Задавал вопрос 2 года назад, а недавно приходит уведомление, что вопрос отмечен как дубликат. При этом указан "оригинал" вопроса, который задавался 6 месяцев (sic!) назад.
 Каким образом мой вопрос является дублем, уж не наоборот ли?
Ссылка на вопрос [Книги по Java EE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/166685/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java-ee)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Вопросы по книгам - оффтопик по правилам SO - книг много, почти любой такой вопрос превращается в полотно ответов, голоса ставятся реально наугад, да еще и книги быстро устаревают.

Т.к. такие вопросы все равно задают - *особо активные пользователи* решили [собрать большой список книг](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/), разбитый по уровню читателя, с аннотациями. Вписать его в один wiki-ответ. А все остальные вопросы-списки закрыть как дубликаты.

Ваш вопрос задан раньше (как и мноие другие вопросы "что почитать по java", но качество ответов на него почти никакое - 3 книги, две из них "автора не помню", без обоснования - почему именно эти 3 книги. Это практически бесполезно для остальных пользователей. Так что закрывающие руководствовались скорее качеством ответов, чем датой вопроса.

Answer (score 9):

В дополнение к PashaPash: вопросы нередко отмечаются как дубликаты заданных позднее, если в более новом вопросе даны гораздо более полные ответы (как в этом случае), либо когда в старом вопросе вообще нет удовлетворительных ответов, а в новом - есть.

Comment: Кстати да, движок не позволяет выбрать вопрос в качестве "главного", если на него есть ответ без голосов "за".

Comment: @PashaPash: может "если нет ответов с голосами "за"? Один плохой ответ не должен блокировать отметку дублем, если есть другие хорошие.

Comment: да, я скорее про случай "ровно один ответ, без голоса за" - часто встречается при массовых дублях от одного пользователя

Comment: @PashaPash: да, эти - отдельная проблема. Можно назвать shotgun-asking, по аналогии с shotgun-debugging.