# Нужны ли списки литературы в формате общих вопросов на ruSO?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, тематика, учебные-материалы

На enSO давно есть возможность помечать сообщения общими, но она практически не используется. Зато на ruSO в этом месяце такой формат стал широко использоваться для хранения списков книг. При этом чётких критериев, какие книги должны добавляться в этот список, на данный момент не существует.
Нужны ли "общие" вопросы с рекомендациями литературы на этом сайте?

Comment: Добавлю, что список более 10 элементов **без вменяемой сортировки и оценки бессмыслен**. Представьте что вы пришли на сайт с играми/книгами/программами. Вы выбрали тему (квест/стихи/органайзеры аналогично темам php/c++), и вам дали просто список по алфавиту. А рейтинги и доп.инфо скрыли. Удобно будет пользоваться?

Comment: К сожалению, комментарии нельзя переносить.

Answer (score 5):

Подобный вопрос уже обсуждался: «[Что делать с вопросами в стиле скажите что почитать?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/)». Результатом обсуждение стало принятие сообществом решения о том, что подобная информация действительно интересна нашим коллегам, которые только начинают свой профессиональный путь и мы, имея какой-то опыт, могли бы им поделиться. По сути, все они (коллеги) задаются одним и тем же вопросом, но с разницей в языке. Поэтому сообщество приняло решение поддерживать список литературы по каждому языку. По сути, такой список – это часть информации, которая могла бы быть в описании самой метки. Вариант с отдельным вопросом выглядит более привлекательно, так как позволяет использовать сортировки по меткам и не перегружает описание.

Обычно за списком литературы приглядывают участники сообщества с высокой репутацией. При внесении любой правки они получат уведомление с внесенными изменениями.

Comment: Перевес голосов по тому обсуждению на данный момент совсем небольшой.

Comment: Думаю, в описаниях меток этим спискам и место. Впрочем, я описания не читаю, потому что они почти никогда не заполнены.

Comment: @Oceinic, перевес увеличил)

Comment: Вам нужно срочно изучить новую предметную область, Физбаззологию, о которой в к сожалению мало знаете. Список литературы предлагает книги на буквы АБВГДЕЖЗМКЛМН. Какая из этих книг классика, а какая лучше? Подсказка, мы, спецы, знаем что книга на ВЕКМ полная фигня, но они в списке т.к. нам нужно заполнить место, БЖ устарели, а ДН это лучшее что может быть! Почувствуйте себя новичком!

Comment: @KromStern, посмотрите на список http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584 - все по полочкам.

Comment: @KromStern, в противном случае новичок просто спросит, что почитать и каждый сунет без объяснений свою книгу, а в конце ему пихнут K&R, независимо от исходной темы.

Comment: @Nofate Вот это годное направление, но я считаю, что даже в таком виде оно не соответствует духу SO. Напомню, что на SO один вопрос = 1 правильный ответ. А тут - четкого вопроса нет и все 100 книг правильный ответ.

Comment: @KromStern, поэтому он оформлен как community question и все собрано в один ответ.

Comment: @Nofate и мы опять возвращаемся к комментарию на 5 выше. Круг замкнулся.

Comment: @KromStern SO != один правильный ответ, лишь один принятый, то есть такой, что, _по мнению автора_, решает описанную проблему лучшим способом.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky и каким образом это помогает рейтинговать книги?

Comment: @KromStern К сожалению, не понял ваш вопрос. Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Вашего комментария  я тоже не понял, поэтому и спросил, как он помогает поиску решения? Выше я уже написал, что простой список малополезен, и чем он длиннее, тем меньше от него пользы. Не важно в виде вики он или нет.

Answer (score 4):

Я не вижу особого смысла в подобных списках книг, когда есть отличные ресурсы с подобным.

Если конкретно про книги говорить, то есть [такой](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md) репозиторий. И я не вижу особого смысла у нас такое заводить. Разве что будет описание каждой книги. Но опять же, это субъективная рецензия будет, что как бы правила нарушает.
Я согласен с тем, что такую информацию лучше прям на страницу метки добавлять.

> В случае, если чётко определённых критериев не будет, что делать с
>   правками, сделанными заинтересованными сторонами (издательство, автор,
>   магазин), каждая из которых считает, что именно их книга лучшая? Если
>   у промоутера будет больше 2000 репутации, эта правка даже не будет
>   проверяться.

А были прецеденты? Я такое только с постами про VPS замечал, когда хостеры сами себя пиарили.

Comment: Прилинкованый список точно так же лишен рейтингов, доп.инфо и сортировок.

Comment: @KromStern да, поэтому и не вижу смысла таких списков у нас )

Comment: "Я не вижу особого смысла в подобных списках книг, когда есть отличные ресурсы с подобным" -- существенное отличие, что тут ТС получает совет от людей, которым он (иначе не спрашивал бы) априори доверяет. Вообще-то, мое мнение, что вместо общих списков лучше было бы иметь ответы от конкретных участников, но большинство (насколько я понимаю) с этим категорически не согласно. Т.о. общие ответы со списками это компромисс. Вопросы же подобного рода будут всегда. И ответы тоже. И все опять и опять будут обижаться, что эти вопросы-ответы закрывают-удаляют. И далее по кругу...

Comment: @avp идея сделать общий ответ хороша, но чьё мнение о книге в него включить?

Comment: Например, все рекомендующие книгу могут записывать свои ники в список под ее описанием.

Comment: @avp о чём это скажет? Важны же не просто ники, а какое-то краткое резюме, + и -

Comment: Ну, резюме к предлагаемой книге желательно в любом случае. Если кто-то из отвечающих (в общем тексте)  имеет особое мнение, то ничто не мешает ему написать еще одно резюме и подписаться именно под ним. Но, это все в идеале. На практике, думаю, мало кто даже свой ник в список к рекомендованной книге не поленится добавить.

Comment: *Я не вижу особого смысла в подобных списках книг, когда есть отличные ресурсы с подобным* - понимаете в чем дело как заметил @avp я не знаю человека/людей которые ведут список *там*, я участвую в этом сообществе, я доверяю мнению людей данного сообщества, и хочу получить рекомендации здесь, и если  постараться то данное высказывание можно подвести под многие темы

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, что списки литературы всё-таки необходимы. Каждое новое поколение программистов будет в своё время осваивать профессию. Кроме того, даже многие профессионалы со временем осваивают новые решения и технологии.

Поэтому, вопросы из серии "что почитать?" будут всегда. В то же время человек, который может что-то посоветовать, есть рядом далеко не всегда. Особенно при самообучении.

Что касается формата. Списками литературы гораздо удобнее пользоваться в виде общих вопросов.

Единственная серьёзная беда таких списков, независимо от формата, это их устаревание. Безусловно, к классикам, таким как Кнут или Страуструп, это не относится. Но в целом литература по конкретным технологиям со временем устаревает. Однако, если за таким списком следят и своевременно его обновляют, влияние данного обстоятельства сводится практически к нулю.

> В случае, если чётко определённых критериев не будет, что делать с
>   правками, сделанными заинтересованными сторонами (издательство, автор,
>   магазин), каждая из которых считает, что именно их книга лучшая?

Если не будет чётко определённых критериев, можно использовать сортировку по алфавиту, году издания и т.д.

Comment: Полагаю, вам стоит узнать, что StackOverflow это не единственный сайт в интернете, а сортировка по алфавиту это  не единственный вид отображения контента

Comment: Вам нужно срочно изучить новую предметную область, Физбаззологию, о которой в к сожалению мало знаете. Список литературы предлагает книги на буквы АБВГДЕЖЗМКЛМН. Какая из этих книг классика, а какая лучше? Подсказка, мы, спецы, знаем что книга на ВЕКМ полная фигня, но они в списке т.к. нам нужно заполнить место, БЖ устарели, а ДН это лучшее что может быть! Почувствуйте себя новичком!

Comment: @Oceinic, я прекрасно в курсе и того и другого.

Comment: @KromStern, впервые слышу чтобы для формирования алфавитного списка обязательно требовалось заполнить разделы для всех букв.

Comment: @Streletz А чем по вашему, например, вот этот список не "алфавит": http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451404. Вот расскажите какая из перечисленных книг шлак, какая для новичков, какая для профи.

Comment: @KromStern, шлак туда не должен попадать. Модерируемые списки как раз должны позволить оградить новичков от *"обучающих видео Попова"*.

Comment: @Nofate вот это правило "шлак туда не должен попадать" достаточно спорно. Кем оно приводится в жизнь? 3-4 авторами, причем инструментов разрешения споров у них нет, и читателю тоже неясно какие книги спорны, а какие маст-хэв. Мое видение вы уже наверно читали - должно быть по типу кинопоиска/любогодругогокаталога, с фильтрами, сортировками, голосами. Но на это движок SO не расчитан.

Answer (score -3):

Считаю создание и поддержание *общих* вопросов со списками книг бессмысленной тратой времени.
По каждой из тематик, таких как [алгоритмы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474415/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-php) или [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) написаны тысячи книг. Но в формате одного ответа вряд-ли получится перечислить больше чем 20-30. Так какие из книг должны войти в их число?
Когда сообщество решит что список стал слишком длинным, потребуется вырабатывать какие-то критерии включения в этот список. Часть из них, вероятно, будут числовыми. Например, в каком году книга переиздавалась (показатель актуальности). Или какой у неё тираж (показатель популярности). Проблема в том, что такие данные лучше показывать в виде таблицы с возможностью сортировки. Но в редакторе SE нет никаких таблиц. Зато они есть на Wikipedia.org. Не лучше ли размещать эту информацию там, где уже есть подходящая инфраструктура?
В случае, если чётко определённых критериев не будет, что делать с правками, сделанными заинтересованными сторонами (издательство, автор, магазин), каждая из которых считает, что именно их книга лучшая? Если у промоутера будет больше 2000 репутации, эта правка даже не будет проверяться.

Answer (score -3):

Изучив мнения участников дискуссии, считаю необходимым перенести эти списки в описания соответствующих меток.

Comment: Такое предложение уже было, но не в виде отдельного ответа

Comment: Я не согласен...

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему?

Comment: Хотя бы потому что описания меток никто не читает. А вообще, отвечу потом, когда время будет.

Comment: К описаниям меток нельзя отмечать дублями новые вопросы.

Comment: @Qwertiy если эта тема никому не интересна, может быть, не стоит и писать о ней?

Comment: @NickVolynkin вопросы можно закрывать и с другими причинами

Comment: @Oceinic важно не закрытие, а чтобы автор вопроса все-таки получил ответ.