# IT-"жаргон", околокомпьютерный диалект

Tags: обсуждение, стиль, русский-язык

В который раз читаю вроде бы хороший, годный ответ... Но как сильно портят что-то хорошее вульгарные (не только по моему мнению) словечки *"винда"*, *"клава"*, *"функционал"*, *"линух"*. Буэээ, аж противно становится (*Не в эмоциональном плане, я не зол, не раздражен, просто нельзя в одном месте мешать жаргон и технически грамотные ответы/вопросы*). **Что в таких случаях делать? Хорошо ли это?** IMHO, это портит ответ, и вообще, это неэтично, непрофессионально и ведет к деградации специалистов.

UPD. После обсуждений в комментариях, я понял,что воспринимать этот ресурс серьёзно не стоит. С одной стороны, здесь не рекомендуют писать приветствий, заставляют форматировать код... называют все это большим словом **ЗНАНИЕ**. С другой стороны, местечковые словечки - это нормально, а профессиональное использование русского языка, наоборот, плохо, ну, по крайней мере, не так уж всем нужно. Я считаю, что нужно стремиться не сорить сленгом в базе знаний. В конце концов, мы же не на mail.ru.

Comment: и что вы предлагаете? :)

Comment: @Grundy я задал довольно риторический вопрос, но на главный вопрос *что делать* я хотел бы править тексты ответов/вопросов с исправлением негодных слов. И правильно ли это, править ответ по этой причине?..

Comment: @approximatenumber неправильно. Потому, что это субъективное мнение. Вам портит слух, а кого-то не напрягает это. И каким образом применение таких слов приводит к деградации? Мне вот интересно. Какие-то эксперименты проводились?)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делать, если вопрос вызывает злость?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Экспериментов нет, конечно. В научном смысле. Но я считаю, что если "специалист" не может называть вещи так, как они называются, т.е. не использует ресурсы главного инструмента человека, - языка, то со временем он деградирует как специалист, в общем смысле. Да, кодить он продолжит, может, также хорошо, но как профессионал он становится хуже.

Comment: @approximatenumber, ну в данном же случае как раз использует и развивает свой язык. И если в вашем языке вещи называются по другому - возможно это вы деградируете? :)

Comment: @Grundy Не в том смысле, я не зол, я образно зол. Я считаю, что на ресурсе, где много говорится про специалистов и про базу знаний... это не к месту.

Comment: @approximatenumber, давайте сначала отучим людей использовать слово "архитектура", где ни попадя.

Comment: @Grundy нет, он его упрощает. Это как мелкие продавцы называет молочные продукты "*молочкой*", некрасиво это. Так профессионалы не разговаривают.

Comment: @approximatenumber, а как разговаривают профессионалы? можете аргументировать почему именно так они должны разговаривать? Как добавление новых слов может упрощать язык? наоборот же - чем больше слов - тем сложнее?

Comment: @approximatenumber это выводы основанные на воздухе и вашем воображении)) Профессионалы порой знаете как говорят? Мат через слово) Можно в таком ключе тогда писать ответы? Но это всего лишь дело вкусовщины.

Comment: @Grundy Откройте хорошую документацию, вот так разговаривают профессионалы. И это не добавление новых слов. Почему, например, подразделение Microsoft не называет свой продукт просто - *операционка винда*?

Comment: @approximatenumber вы уверены что они ее так не называют? не в маркетинговых материалах, а между собой.

Comment: @approximatenumber, кстати - "феня" - это "жаргон" по фене. Исправьте вопрос, пожалуйста. Заменив слово "феня" на "Профессиональный жаргон". А то от слова "феня" у меня аж буээ.

Comment: "IMHO" - тоже не украшает речь специалиста, как по мне ("как по мне" - вполне можно использовать вместо "IMHO"). 
Что же касается правок вопросов/ответов. Если они сделают их более выразительными и понятными, то почему нет.

Comment: @approximatenumber, а может называя Windows *виндой* специалист как раз специально показывает свое отноошение к этой ОС и тем кто в ней работает? Почему Вы хотите лишить его этого удовольствия?

Comment: @avp То есть, говоря так, он выражает свои эмоции, а не знания, что тоже не очень хорошо его характеризует :)

Comment: @approximatenumber то есть по-вашему профессионал - это бесчувственный робот, который следует инструкциям?

Comment: @PashaPash именно поэтому слово "феня" я заключил в кавычки

Comment: @approximatenumber это называется ["Профессиональный жаргон"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD). Абсолютно нормальная вещь. Никто в здравом уме не будет писать полное название "Операционная система Windows". И, кстати, как проработавший пару месяцев на большом молочном заводе - могу точно сказать - молочную продукцию называют "молочкой" все в этой отрасли.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский То есть специалист, который владеет своим родным языком, умеет грамотно излагать свои мысли, это робот?:-)

Comment: @approximatenumber да во что угодно заключайте - вы все равно назвали (сравнили) профессиональный жаргон "феней", тем самым выразив свое *личное* отношение к нему, и заодно практически уровняв нас с урками.

Comment: @approximatenumber грамотно != слэнг

Comment: @approximatenumber, эмоционально поданные знания часто воспринимаются лучше долготных и сухих текстов. А вообще, не стоит подгонять всех под себя.

Comment: Используйте профессионально русский язык, никто не говорит вам, что это плохо.

Comment: Хорошо. Товарищи, скажите, я не прав в том, что "линух" оскорбительно звучит для Linux, а "клава" - для клавиатуры?

Comment: За всех не скажу, но меня не оскорбляет. А то ведь придется писать не "жесткий диск", а "накопитель на жестких магнитных дисках". Не "память", а "оперативное запоминающее устройство".

Comment: При правках я заменяю "линух" на "Linux". Но не делаю правки только ради этого.

Comment: @Nofate я не прошу утрировать и доходить до абсурда,но по мере сил стараться говорить правильно, это же хорошо.

Comment: Доходить до абсурда не стоит. Но когда вы предлагаете общее правило, вас непременно спросят "Где грань?". Посмотрите соседнюю тему про *этику*, для примера.

Comment: @Nofate Вот мне и интересно, где грань. Я не собираюсь устраивать граммарнаци-войны, но пропускать мимо сленг сложно. Ладно, если ответ так себе, но когда ответ хорош, то я считаю, он должен быть также хорошо написан. Ну, желательно...

Comment: @approximatenumber, главное не перегибать палку. Коллективная правка постов - хорошо. Конфликты из-за правки - плохо.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Как правило, **стоит** делать правку ради этого лишь в следующих случаях:

- Когда весь ответ написан наспех и с большим количеством ошибок, но информация в нём представляет ценность: если автор просто «привык в интернете так общаться».
  Это плохо, автора стоит от этого отучить, но если автор отказывается отучаться, то авторство не повод заставлять читателей страдать.
  Автор, скорее всего, не будет против, но об этом ниже.
- Когда языковых ошибок в ответе немного, но термин используется *исключительно в жаргонной форме*. В этой ситуации можно при первом упоминании жаргонизма «растолковать» его в скобках.
  По аналогии с «локальной переменной», чтобы на неё ссылаться, её для начала нужно объявить и инициализировать.

...и только при условии, что у вас есть 2000+ репутации и ваша правка не отправится в очередь, где её просмотрят и обдумают ещё несколько человек. Но об этом чуть позже.

---

Я стараюсь подобные жаргонизмы *в ответах* использовать минимально. **Но это я.**

Я считаю, что они **хороши** по целому ряду причин при **обсуждении** (в чате, в комментариях) соответствующих сущностей:

- они, обычно, короче и проще в произношении;
- можно использовать как «синонимическую разгрузку» (вместе с «правильными»);
- не требуют переключения раскладки (что бывает особенно удобно на телефонах);
- имеют эмоциальную окраску (сообщения всё-таки авторские и у автора есть **мнение**).

**...но не для документирования!** В ответах часть этих доводов не действует. Ответ *письменный* и удобствами в произношении обладать не обязан, а если редактор ответов не позволяет написать *нормально* (например, Android-клиент, если, конечно, вы не используете физическую клавиатуру), доберитесь до *нормального* редактора и напишите ответ *по-нормальному*. (Или хотя бы приведите его в порядок позже.)

---

Можно ли редактировать чужие ответы **единственно** ради исправления ситуации с терминами? **Явного запрета на это нет,** но важно:

- избежать конфликта с автором

  - скажем, если он *задумывал* придать эмоциональную окраску
- не изменить смысловой нагрузки ответа/вопроса

  - или, как минимум, *не уменьшить её*

**Всё остальное вытекает уже из этого.**

Автор может воспротивиться. У него могут быть причины, *не ввязывайтесь в войны правок*: просто **проходите мимо** или **подкиньте эту тему [на обсуждение в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)**.

В контексте правок поперёк автора мы идём обычно лишь в случае **вандализма**: правок, направленных на уничтожение ценных сведений. И обычно это сопровождается вмешательством (или хотя бы участием) модератора.

---

Но есть ещё деталь. **Предлагаемые правки** от тех, у кого ещё недостаточно репутации для осуществления "непроверяемых правок" (менее 2000). Правки, исключительно исправляющие такие термины, могут счесть *незначительными* или *противоречащими намерениям автора* и **отклонить**, потому что этот механизм предназначен для правок, качество и значимость которых не вызывает ни малейших сомнений.

Comment: D-side, ещё 2 момента бы затронули: **[1]** Арго затрудняет понимание понимание текста для тех, кто плохо знает русский язык и/или сам жаргон. //  **[2]** Усложняется доступ к материалам Stack Overflow через поисковики, т. к. большинство всё же будет вводить в поисковую форму «клавиатура», а не «клава». Поэтому полагаю, что в заголовках вопросов исправлять сленговые термины на литературный русский необходимо. // Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных на самом деле, обе этих проблемы в ответе *уже* вскользь упомянуты. Я предлагаю в местах, где термин встречается **только** в виде жаргонизма, единожды "растолковывать" него. Это же решит проблему поисковиков: ведь как минимум один раз термин в ответе встретится в нормальной форме. Про заголовок сходу сказать не могу, я больше думал об ответах, чем о вопросах, а редактирование вопросов обычно идёт несколько более свободно, т. к. часто похоже, что "автор не шарит".

Comment: @СашаЧерных лично для  меня слово "арго" затрудняет понимание вашего комментария. )

Answer (score 9):

На этом сайте именно диктатура знаний и это выражается не только в том, что принято вырезать приветствия — но и во всех мелочах.

Я, например, помимо знаний по профессии обладаю ещё и высокими навыками в области русского языка. Даже когда-то хотел стать писателем, а не программистом, просто затянуло меня в «программинг» с головой и до сих пор «не отпускает».

И поскольку у нас диктатура знаний, если я вижу сообщение менее грамотного человека, то я имею полное право вмешиваться и править по своему усмотрению запятые, орфографию или вычищать слово «типа», если оно мне вдруг не понравится. Или если вдруг [найдётся](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/609261/revisions) человек, который ещё лучше разбирается и поправит меня в чём-то, то, думаете, я оскорблюсь, расстроюсь? Пожму плечами и возьму на заметку, что тут я ошибся и надо стараться не повторить.
Имеете полное право назвать это именно диктатурой, если вам так нравится этот термин.

Мне лично как-то повезло в жизни: я всегда знал, что какой бы умный ты ни был, всегда найдётся кто-то умнее тебя. И что во всём одновременно быть умным невозможно. Поэтому Stack Overflow — это моё место и мне тут нравится: здесь люди ориентированы на знание.

Поэтому если у меня рука на автопилоте тянется поправить пару букв в сообщении — я беру и правлю. Меня никто к этому не обязывает, хочу — делаю, не хочу — не делаю. Мы тут не филиал заведения для благородных девиц, поэтому знание нас интересует в первую очередь техническое, а запятые-орфография во вторую, в основном только потому, что инженер — это высокообразованный специалист и не будет писать с ошибками, потому что уважает и себя, и других.

Но всё вышесказанное не означает, что тут обязывают к принудительной грамотности! Сказал «клава» — фсё, иди и убей сибя апстену! Сказал «айтем» — вали с ресурса, тут только для белых людей и для тех, кто в совершенстве владеет и русским, и английским!

Не нужно заставлять людей делать это! Принуждение — та вещь, которая убивает любой интерес и ведёт к конфликтам. Если вы обязываете людей использовать строгий словарь терминов, да многие уйдут, крутя пальцем у виска.

Поэтому я однозначно против такого подхода: всем построиться и в обязательном порядке использовать только официально утверждённые фразы. И в голове у меня совершенно спокойно уживается с «диктатурой знаний», не вижу никаких противоречий.

Поэтому если вам хочется соблюдать высокие стандарты — пишите свои собственные сообщения «высоким штилем», правьте чужие — но не требуйте это прописать в обязательных правилах ruSO.

От себя могу добавить правила правки чужих сообщений, они банальны и общеизвестны:

1. Не достигли репутации в 2к+ — не делайте правок только в русском языке: они попадут на проверку к пятерым людям, которые будут их отклонять с формулировкой "никак не улучшает сообщение", потому что первично улучшение именно технической стороны (также в форме не предусмотрен вариант «перестаньте отвлекать пятерых человек», но этот «мессидж» тоже должен дойти до вас)
2. Если достигли репутации в 2к+ и хотите тратить своё время на расстановку запятых и правку мелких орфографических ошибок — да ради бога! Никто вас не поддержит, но и не осудит. По сути, это мелкая волонтёрская работа: неоплачиваемая, мало ценимая, но важная с общественной точки зрения. Может, вас это согреет, а может, просто будете править — изредка, по настроению, от души.
3. Не стоит никогда делать правки, сильно искажающие авторский стиль. Иной оборот может быть уместен ради подчёркивания какой-то мысли, а бывает что и всё сообщение такое, что не стоит в одном месте править — нужно весь текст переписать, но тогда от исходного текста автора мало чего останется.
4. Если автор захочет вернуть своё сообщение в исходный вид — не настаивайте. Просто скажите, что вы хотели сделать лучше. Неважно, кто из вас прав — просто верните, как было.

P.S. И последнее, но пожалуй, наиболее важное. Будьте толерантны к другим людям!

Comment: НА будущее... не относится к ответу)) Тире (длинное) — `Alt + 0151`
Короткое (среднее) тире  — `Alt + 0150`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я ещё на память помню, как кавычки ёлочками вставить ))) Но когда я пишу текст -- я ставлю двойной дефис, для скорости. Это элемент моего авторского стиля и способ ещё чуть больше выжать из слепого десятипальцевого набора. Если кому не лень за мной править -- может заменять, а я буду писать так, как хочу. (Не напоминает одного человека с ru-so, который предложения начинает с маленькой буквы?) Меня например больше интересует, почему ворд или вконтакт заменяет двойной дефис на "эм даш", а stackoverflow не может? )))

Comment: Странно, `когда-то хотел стать писателем`  и `Но когда я пишу текст -- я ставлю двойной дефис, для скорости` ....... так вы за русиш язиш или всё же "пишу как хочу лишь бы быстро"? Определились бы)

Comment: `хотел стать писателем, а не программистом` – думаю, вы можете стать выдающимся техническим писателем.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Позиция

- **заменять любые жаргонизмы,**
- **не препятствовать, не вставлять палки в колёса тем, кто этим занимается,**
- **ставить минусы сообщениям особо злоупотребляющих жаргоном участникам, которым уже обращали внимание на их лексику.**

---

***Аргументация***:

---

### 2. Неудобство для иноязычных пользователей

Отнюдь не обладающий обширными знаниями английского языка, являюсь частым посетителем, например, Stack Overflow на английском, Super User и Software Recommendations. Когда сообщение на вышеперечисленных сайтах расписано грамотно, на литературном английском, обычно удаётся понять его. Но если оно изобилует какими-то понятными по большей части лишь тем, для кого английский язык является родным, сокращениями; эмоционально окрашенными выражениями; словами, непонятными для [**QTranslate**](https://quest-app.appspot.com/), — приходится тратить время в поисковиках на то, чтобы разобраться в сообщении, а обыкновенно — просто-напросто домысливать за автора сообщения, что тот хотел.

Stack Overflow на русском могут читать не только пользователи, для которых язык является родным. Программы и сервисы для перевода переводят жаргонизмы далеко не всегда: так, Google Translate переводит [**клава как Claudia**](https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru#ru/en/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0). Притом жаргон может быть не общеупотребительным, а используемым лишь в узких кругах или вовсе только автором сообщения — приходилось видеть, как `.htaccess` называли `хитачес` и [**даже `хачес`**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=29491784#29491784).

Stack Overflow на русском — [**сайт с огромной посещаемостью**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4326/199934), рискну предположить (официальной статистики не нашёл), что на него заходят далеко не только пользовательницы/пользователи интернета, для которых русский является родным языком. Личный пример: несмотря на то, что я осуществляю поиск информации по проблеме на `google.com` и сразу на английском языке, — в топе поисковой выдачи нередко оказываются результаты со Stack Overflow на русском.

---

### 3. Поисковые системы

Данные [**Wordstat Яндекс**](https://wordstat.yandex.ru/) на момент написания данного сообщения:

- [**не работает клавиатура**](https://wordstat.yandex.ru/#!/?words=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) — 79341 показ в месяц;
- [**не работает клава**](https://wordstat.yandex.ru/#!/?words=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0) — 3158 показов в месяц.

Да, составляются и будут составляться поисковые запросы, содержащие жаргонную лексику, но обычно всё-таки вводят общеупотребительные термины. Если это так, то при употреблении жаргонной лексики на веб-ресурсе:

1. Труднее найти информацию по проблеме, с которой они столкнулась/столкнулся,
2. Произойдёт снижение позиций сайта в поисковой выдаче, чему наверняка не сильно обрадуются его владелицы/владельцы.

Особенно, на мой взгляд, следует уделить внимание отсутствию сленга в заголовках — как элементов, имеющих большй вес для краулеров.

---

### 4. Энциклопедичность, качество

Сотрудники Stack Exchange говорят об «энциклопедии», «базе знаний». Повышает ли качество ресурсов сети использование арго? На мой взгляд нет, сообщения становятся менее энциклопедичными, согласен с аргументами ув-мого [**@approximatenumber**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2903/199934).

Stack Overflow на русском уже имеет достаточную репутацию, чтобы отдельные пользователи подстраивались под требования сайта, а не наоборот.

---

### 5. Ответы на комментарии

К сожалению, комментарии в отношении [**вопроса**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2903/199934) нового пользователя Меты снова [**оставляют желать лучшего**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4038/199934). Попробуем разобрать некоторые поступившие в них рациональные аргументы.

#### 1. Эмоциональность.

> а может называя Windows виндой специалист как раз специально показывает свое отношение к этой ОС и тем кто в ней работает?
>
> скажем, если он задумывал придать эмоциональную окраску

1. А нужны ли вообще в базе знаний эмоциональные выражения? Энциклопедии стараются придерживаться нейтрального стиля.
2. К сожалению, в интернете легко высказывать неаргументированные неприятные вещи в отношении кого или чего-либо. Считаю подобный подход неконструктивным. Вместо того, чтобы сказать «джисон — отвратный формат», можно [**сделать так**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/566060/199934):

> [**Не только я**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/247473/#comment_8213839) считаю, что JSON менее удобен в сравнении с [**Hjson**](https://hjson.org/) или YAML, в частности, потому что если в файле находятся комментарии или запятая в конце массива, он [**становится невалидным**](https://plus.google.com/+DouglasCrockfordEsq/posts/RK8qyGVaGSr).

К негативной оценке я стараюсь присовокуплять аргументы и/или ссылки на источники, где выражено похожее оценочное мнение; с неодобрением относясь к оценкам без аргументов.

#### 2. Что считать «жаргонным термином»?

> Абсолютно нормальная вещь. Никто в здравом уме не будет писать полное название "Операционная система Windows".
>
> А то ведь придется писать не "жесткий диск", а "накопитель на жестких магнитных дисках". Не "память", а "оперативное запоминающее устройство"

В филологических источниках атрибутом жаргонных терминов почему-то указывается экспрессивность. Хотя мне, например, больше кажется, что употребляя на письме слово «клава» автору обычно просто неохота писать более длинное «клавиатура». Однако и без этого можно ввести разграничение, которое будет работать в большинстве случаев, например:

> ```
> Жаргонным считается термин, не употребляемый в авторитетных источниках по теме (за исключением источников, исследующих жаргон), выдержанных в нейтральном стиле.
> ```

В серьёзных книгах (кроме, как нарочно, выдержанных в эмоционально украшенном стиле) не будут писать «клава», «винда» или «линух», в отличие от «Windows» и «жёсткий диск». «Память» также не рекомендовал бы употреблять: иноязычные и не знакомые со сленгом пользователи могут растолковать слово в другом значении. Тем более, в данном конкретном случае можно применить короткую аббревиатуру ОЗУ.

#### 3. Общеупотребительность сленга

> И, кстати, как проработавший пару месяцев на большом молочном заводе - могу точно сказать - молочную продукцию называют "молочкой" все в этой отрасли.
>
> вы уверены что они ее так не называют? не в маркетинговых материалах, а между собой.

1. Допустим, для получения знаний я читаю литературу, которую [**пользователи Stack Overflow считают качественной**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2078/199934) и хорошие ответы на Stack Overflow. А зачем мне знать сленговую терминологию? Только ли чтобы понимать, что пишут на ресурсах с низкой культурой модерации? Если пользователь не знаком с общеупотребительным термином, это его проблемы; а виноват ли он, не зная арго?

   И по опыту: жаргон, о котором пишут в книгах, заметно отличается от жаргона употребляемого в речи. Как его учить?
2. Сленг (и то, не весь, см. п.2) понятен как раз специалистам, но ведь Stack Overflow на русском читают и люди, делающие первые шаги в изучении программирования и смежных с ним тематик. Дружественность ресурса по отношении к этой категории пользовательниц/пользователей снижается при наличии в нём жаргонной лексики.

   Можно называть клавиатуру «клавой» между собой, когда собеседницы/собеседники не возражают против сленга, и им понятно значение, но не тогда, когда результат виден всем категориям посетительниц/посетителей сайта, включая начинающих и иноязычных программистов.

---

### 6. Транслит

Отдельного обсуждения, на мой взгляд, заслуживает тема допустимости замены транслитерированных слов, пример: [**пикче бокс → Picture Box, автоскрол → AutoScroll**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/610695/revisions) (опустим рассмотрение [**Mocha**](https://mochajs.org/) или [**Hayaku**](https://github.com/hayaku/hayaku)). [**Здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/432617/revisions), например, модератор отклонил правку `мокап` → `mockup` с комментарием «Заимствованные слова понятны».

мне вряд ли много приходится сталкиваться с данной проблемой, читая англоязычные ресурсы, — с английского на английский нечего транслитерировать, — однако, подозреваю, что у пользовательниц/пользователей, чьим родным языком не является русский, возникают трудности с пониманием транслитерированных текстов.

Спасибо.

#### 7. [**Аналогия**](http://kristinita.ru/Giologica/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE#1.3)

А, да, «Спасибо» же писать нельзя, применяются даже [**автоматические меры**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4394/199934) для борьбы с благодарностями. Притом

- Прочтение «Привет» или «Спасибо» занимает доли секунды, тогда как на выяснение значения сленгового термина времени уходит больше;
- Приветствия и благодарности не несут негативной коннотации в отличие от некоторых жаргонных терминов.

Comment: Лично моя позиция: когда на ru.so станет официально принято вычищать жаргонизмы и это начнется с моими сообщениями, я свалю отсюда нафиг) Если бы я хотел писать сухую статью в википедии или научную работу - я бы это делал. Я же пишу свои ответы в надежде что они помогут кому-то, кто говорит на моем языке.

Comment: С минусами только за «неверный набор терминов», не согласен. В остальном обоими руками поддерживаю! Более того, в самом начале пути мы именно так и делали. В определенный момент, когда поток вопросов возрос, стало банально не хватать времени, после чего привлекли корректора исключительно для этой задачи.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Мне кажется, если не впадать в крайности, то использования именно русского языка пойдет только на пользу. К примеру, ваши сообщения я бы не стал исправлять, но существует множество людей, которые, к примеру, билдят, затем перебилживают и еще что–то не понятное, хотя существует вполне прекрасное слово «сборка», «собирать проект» и тд

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ну понятно что крайности в целом вредят, но провести границу - чертовски сложно. Мне кажется авторский стиль достоин правки в двух случаях: 1. это явные ошибки-опечатки (а не нарочитые, то есть если аффтар пишит таг, то это его проблемы). 2. вопрос настолько непонятен что его закрывают как непонятный.

Comment: [Благодарности и приветствия](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/95/6) удаляются, так как они не повышают качество представленной информации. Отказ от жаргонизмов, наоборот, улучшает читаемость сообщений. Аналогия, на мой взгляд, не до конца верная.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я также последовательно выступаю против удаления благодарностей и приветствий) Но это другой вопрос. Отказываясь от жаргонизмов - мы впадаем в другую крайность. Тезис "отказ от жаргонизмов улучшает читаемость сообщений" верен в целом по больнице, но может убить конкретного пациента.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Очень сложный вопрос, на самом деле. Писать грамотно – чертовски приятно. Это как использовать нужные шаблоны проектирования в правильном месте. Авторский стиль, безусловно важен, что более критично, на мой взгляд, если мы начнем всех постоянно поправлять (я имею в виду через указание на недостаток в комментарии). С другой стороны, представьте, если бы в промышленных проектах ценилось бы не читаемость и понятность кода, а авторский стиль? Мне бы, к примеру, такое не понравилось. С другой стороны, шаблоны можно использовать по–разному.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, примеры сообщений, где Вы используете жаргонизмы, можно посмотреть? Глянул сейчас на список Ваших лучших ответов — ни в одном из них не нашёл сленговых терминов. Спасибо.

Comment: Потому что хороший ответ во многих случаях - это не точно сформулированный непогрешимый ответ. Это ответ который легко и быстро составит у вопрошающего правильную ментальную модель. Жаргонизмы иногда в этом здорово помогают.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а Вы по финансовым или каким-то другим причинам отказались от услуг Виталины? Спасибо.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму  Если говорить о модели, то только слово на родном языке может вызывать какой–либо эмоциональный отклик, и, как результат, более или менее одинаковую интерпретацию.

Comment: @СашаЧерных По политике партии. Она заключается в том, что нельзя насаживать решения с верху. Если сообщество считает необходимым поддерживать качество сообщений, именно оно должно этим и заниматься. Не существует других способов поддержать высокое качество _прикладных_ знаний в базе такого размера.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, ох, мне если честно влом шерстить свои старые ответы, но я точно знаю что всякие сомнительные словечки использую.  К примеру из проф словечек легко заменимых русскоязычными в моих топ ответах "дамп, кастомные, инлайновый", "запихаем" ну и тд.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, в общем суть в том, что итак написание нормального ответа на so сложная задача - за любую сомнительную формулировку могут спросить коллеги. А Вы предлагаете еще при этом думать о чистоте языка, что превратит написание ответа лично для меня в слишком затратную операцию.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky с тезисом я согласен, если считать "родным языком" - реальный язык, а не то что в словаре написано, преподается на уроках или требуется партией радетелей за чистоту языка с so.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, о, нашел, я очень люблю употреблять слово "спека", например тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611660/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-w3c-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-document-body/611664#611664

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Спека – это вполне прижившееся слово (спецификация). Не считается!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, чем оно отличается от слов "винда", "клава", "функционал" и "линух"? Если я пишу ответ, где мне провалидировать его на вхождение жаргонных слов?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, про «спеку» [**не сказал бы**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=спека+это). На мой взгляд, это как раз слово, подлежащее замене. Спасибо.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Для меня оно сильно отличается, например, от «билдить» или «сорцы» (что есть «исходный/программный код» или просто «код»).

Comment: @СашаЧерных [Забавно!](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0) Никогда бы не подумал.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, в том и проблема. Вот для меня билдить и сорцы и спека - нормальные слова. Для вас спека - ок, а билдить и сорцы - не ок, для Саша Черных - все три не ок. Как провалидировать, нормальный я ответ пишу, или его правками зарежут? Для грамматики ладно, можно спеллчекер натравить. А для проверки допустимости лексики уже не все так просто.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, понял Вашу точку зрения, спасибо.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, а для меня для чтения приемлемы все, но "билдить" я напишу запросто, а "спека" и "сорцы" - маловероятно. Впрочем, второе я почти гарантированно заменю на "исходники" (а не "исходный код") так что всё жаргонизм получится :D Что касается "Линух" - он же не Тех - почему бы не написать обе буквы "кс" как полагается? А вот "Винда" выглядит лучше чем транслит "Виндоуз".

Comment: Сленг — нормальная часть живого языка. Не пытайтесь убить язык сообщества, это бессмысленно.

Answer (score 0):

В ответах выше не хватает примеров.

- Вот это править не надо:

> Во время игры клавиатура отключилась и пропала подсветка, вытянул с usb-порта, вставил обратно, звук был, что она подключилась, но клавиатура не работает.
> Захожу в ПО Dark Project, пишет: подключите клавиатуру. В настройках **винды** она определяется как wpm usb.

- А это пример, почему злоупотребление жаргонизмами делает сообщение нечитаемым (некрасивым):

> Трабл: подрубил клаву к компу (юзаю винду). При гейме она вырубилась, переподключил юсбишку, пикнуло, но всё равно клава не пашет.

<sup>Примеры — переработанный текст [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1518288/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0).</sup>

Comment: А почему первое править **не** надо?

Comment: @чистов_n об этом ответы выше. Не надо править только один жаргонизм. Если их несколько/есть что ещё править, то уже стоит.