# Какой [mint] должен стать основным?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Надо бы синонимизировать метки [mint](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mint) и [linux-mint](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint). К какой из них?

Comment: Перенести надо вопросы из mint в linux-mint, а mint удалить. Там их всего 42 штуки.

Comment: @Visman, я вообще синонимом хотел. Но забыл, т. к. не нашёл, где они назначаются... Надо попробовать...

Comment: @Visman, [брррррррррр](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4033/178988)...

Comment: @Visman, у меня не хватает рейтинга по метке, чтобы предложить синоним.

Comment: @Qwertiy Объединено не в ту сторону. Можете, пожалуйста, исправить и добавить [meta-tag:статус-завершено]?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, готово.

Comment: @Qwertiy У меня почему-то [tag:linux-mint] переводит на [tag:mint]. Кеш или недоделано?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, не знаю.. У меня тоже. Давай подождём до завтра - может всё-таки кэш...

Comment: @Qwertiy Ура, всё работает как надо!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[linux-mint](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint). Потому что дистрибутив называется именно "Linux Mint" и под названием просто "Mint" лично я (как его пользователь) видел всего в двух контекстах:

- короткий идентификатор дистрибутива (упоминается в RVM при установке зависимостей)
- в разговорах (см. [о жаргонизмах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2904/181100))

В домене, на логотипе и в названиях образов он называется именно "Linux Mint", `linuxmint` или иным образом, подходящим под `/linux.*mint/i`.