# Поддомен meta.ru. живёт в комментариях

Tags: дефект, комментарии, ссылки

Нашёл [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3996/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-mint-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC?noredirect=1#comment13223_3996), в котором написана ссылка в старом формате `https://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4033/178988`. Насколько я понимаю, когда менялся формат адреса, Дух проходил по всем сообщениям и исправлял его. Почему же в этом комментарии осталось `meta.ru.`, а не изменилось на `ru.meta`?

Comment: Исправьте самостоятельно и забудьте.

Comment: Ответ уже есть в вопросе: менялись **сообщения**, а ссылка в **комментарии**. А комментарии, как известно, сущности довольно легко убиваемые.

Answer (score 4):

На данный момент таких комментариев 340, я это узнал [через SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/851133) с помощью запроса

```sql
SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE Text LIKE N'%meta.ru.stackoverflow.com%';
```

Довольно немало, а также надо учесть, что этот дефект, скорее всего, затронул и другие сообщества сети Stack Exchange, поэтому его, возможно, следует описать на главной мете.