# Надо ли переводить на русский язык английские слова написанные русскими буквами?

Tags: обсуждение, перевод-содержимого

У нас на сайте есть такие слова и фразы которые немного смущают:

- "плиз хелп"
- "туториал"
- "либа"
- "таска"
- "инсталировать"
- "директория"
- "пофиксить"
- "гайд"
- ...

Я их часто перевожу, но всё таки не всегда.

У нас вопросы не на русском языке не приветствуются полностью. А вот так, написанные отчасти на английском видимо привествуются приветствуются.

**Так надо ли переводить эти слова и/или фразы?**

Comment: Это устойчивая часть айтишного слэнга, бороться с этим бессмысленно. (Слово "директория" я видел в методичках по DOS, изданных в начале 90х)

Comment: Уже обсуждали, что делать правки *только* ради таких исправлений не стоит. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2903

Comment: Еще одно эпичное обсуждение: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9508/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет. Не стоит придираться к таким мелочам самим по себе. Англицизмы сами по себе неизбежная часть всего айтишного.

Если же делается более существенная правка, то попутно можно попробовать привести такие слова к более общепринятым и/или грамотным (винда - Windows, рест - REST, юзвери - пользователи, итп).