# Можно ли задавать вопросы типа "какую литературу почитать ... ?"

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика, учебные-материалы

Вопрос данного типа не удовлетворяет критерию:

> ...должен иметь однозначный ответ

но есть прецеденты, когда вопросы типа "какой самый лучший софт ..." набирали сотни апвойтов, при этом на них давались развёрнутые ответы. Вот пример [вопроса](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) с TeX Stack Exchange о лучшем редакторе для TeX, набравший 781 апвойт, 608 звёзд и две страницы ответов.

Кстати, я бы хотел узнать, что почитать на тему синтаксического анализа для создания собственных языков программирования, подсветки и валидации синтаксиса для них и так далее.

Comment: ответ на оффтопик оставлю в комментариях: поищите тут https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [А что если разрешить спрашивать мнение об инструментах, библиотеках, книгах и т.п?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/623/%d0%90-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d1%82)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [официальной справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) есть раздел в котором прямо говорится, что есть вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать:

> Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по
>   программированию и администрированию. Для списков литературы выделены
>   особые поддерживаемые сообществом вопросы. Вместо того, чтобы задавать
>   новый вопрос, найдите уже существующий в вопросе-указателе. Также
>   список литературы и других ресурсов часто можно найти в описаниях
>   меток по соответствующим темам.

Подобный вопрос также освещался на мете:

- [Что делать с вопросами в стиле "скажите что почитать"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/213987)
- [Нужны ли списки литературы в формате общих вопросов на ruSO?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2075/213987)

Правильно: отправлять спрашивающих в подобные темы. Суровая правда жизни в том, что за этими вопросами особо никто не следит и когда спрашивают "что почитать" — это почти всегда ситуация, когда вот именно этого в списке нету. В литературе вечные хиты, а чего-то узкоспециализированного нету и приходится самому ресёч делать. И — все хотят потреблять контент, но мало кто готов хорошую прочитанную книгу добавить в список литературы.

Я могу сказать так. Очень полезно читать книги для саморазвития и то, что на so не особо много можно найти рекомендаций — это печаль и для участников и точка развития для сайта. (В других местах всё ещё хуже) Однако как ни плох закон — нужно ему следовать, соблюдать до момента, когда его не улучшат.

Если есть предложения что делать с ситуацией - предлагайте, мета как раз для этого. Предварительно рекомендую ознакомиться с прошлыми темами, чтобы не начинать с одного и того же места.

Comment: Насколько мне помнится, самоуправления у нас нет, так что «предлагайте» я бы уточнил как «попробуйте обосновать для администрации полезность расширения онтопика».

Answer (score 0):

Можно конечно , жизнь тяжела и вопросов много , посему без хорошей книжонки не разберешься :3

*Но, так так явно нельзя спрашивать, то завуалированно надо спрашивать ^_^*