# Нужны ли видеокурсы в списках литературы и учебных материалов?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, учебные-материалы

В [обсуждении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474385/199934) предложили вынести этот вопрос на Мету. Лично я считаю, что качественные актуальные видеокурсы не навредят, а только наоборот, но здесь есть такие, кто считает иначе. Хотелось бы услышать их аргументы равно как и тех, кто не против видеокурсов.

Напоминаю, что сообщество [голосовало](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/162/199934) не за удаление самих списков литературы и учебных материалов.

Answer (score 23):

Почему видеокурсы не подходят для этого списка:

- Их очень, очень много. Только на ютубе есть около [4 940 000 результатов по запросу 'java'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=java).

  - Наш список явно не вместит такое количество роликов.
  - Поиск видеохостинга всегда будет работать лучше и давать более понятный результат, чем наш список.
- Вместе с большим количеством приходит низкое качество. Каждый школьник, пройдя туториалы по Unity 3d, считает своим долгом снять учебный ролик про то, как создать на нём свою игру.

  - Оценка качества субъективна. Мы не сможем выработать объективный критерий, по которому можно/нельзя добавлять конкретное видео.
  - Следовательно, в списки будут попадать ролики сколь угодно низкого качества.
- Видео всегда снимает кто-то. От Google до Василия Пупкина, все имеют свой канал на ютубе с лекциями. И в этих лекциях есть ссылки на сайт автора, на платные курсы, пиар какого-нибудь продукта и т.п. Ссылки на видео будут как минимум похожи на спам. Нередко это и будет спам от заинтересованного лица.

  - Например, [в двух последних правках в списке по Javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/474386/revisions), которые пришлось откатить, были добавлены ссылки на ресурсы двух различных коммерческих организаций.
- Последней упомяну классическую причину: такие ссылки легко протухают. Книги условно бессмертны, а видео легко удалить ([подробнее в соседнем ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3415/181472)).

Comment: **1** и **2**. Предложено добавлять только качественные материалы. С книгами тут ведь происходит то же самое. Ресурс как раз будет «отделять зёрна от плевел».// **3**. Авторы книг тоже работают не бесплатно. В чём разница? // **4**. Насчёт качественных так не думаю. Авторам курсов это явно невыгодно. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных предложите способ определения качества видеокурса? книг все таки на порядок меньше

Comment: @Bald, > книг все таки на порядок меньше — на что-то влияет этот аргумент? Насчёт как книг книг, так и курсов гуглю по советам специалистов по тематике, желательно, незаинтересованных.

Comment: *книг все таки на порядок меньше — на что-то влияет этот аргумент?* - на то что поддерживать/верифицировать/актуализировать список литературы намного проще, я все таки жду *способ определения качества видеокурса*. *Семен Алексеев | Видеокурс C# 5.0. От простого к сложному (2013)* это качественный или шлак

Comment: @Bald, **1**. каково отличие между способом определения качества видеокурса и книги? Как делаю я, сказал в предыдущем комментарии. // **2**. Если что-то не так просто, значит ли это, что от этого чего-то нужно отказываться?

Comment: @СашаЧерных книг как минимум меньше, а хороших книг и подавно и все они на слуху. видеокурсов же *сто тысяч милионов* и становится только больше, ладно я бы еще понял лекции от *светил* программирования...

Comment: Это скорее аргументы за, а не против.

Answer (score 17):

Нет, не нужны:

- Порог входа для съёмки видеокурса заметно ниже, чем для написания книги. Это сказывается на качестве материала в видеокурсах.
- Книги сильнее защищены от забвения. У них есть глобальные стандартные идентификаторы (ISBN), которые здорово упрощают поиск в отрыве от источников распространения. Видеокурсы же обычно размещаются на одном видеохостинге и не сохраняются зрителями нигде, кроме временного кэша. Это техническая особенность самого удобного для пользователей (и потому самого популярного) способа доставки видеокурсов: веб-браузера с потоковым вещанием. Если на хостинге они станут недоступны, то достать их в общественных источниках будет невозможно.
- Текстовый формат намного более удобен для изучения, чем видео. Поиск по тексту тривиален, найти в видео нужную фразу на текущем уровне развития технологии невозможно -- можно лишь приблизительно кликнуть на нужное место в видео. Вставка примеров кода из видео невозможна - и по этому параметру также проигрывает тексту и чем длиннее фрагмент кода -- тем наглядее это видно. Даже если просто слушать видео в метро: чуть отвлечёшься -- и крайне сложно в плейере отмотать на три секунды назад.
- ...

Comment: Лекционная форма занятий, когда кто-то что-то читает без обратной связи с аудиторией, устарела с момента появления книгопечатанья.

Воспринимать на слух можно только какие-то общие концепции, вроде "в CPP легко отстрелить себе ногу"

В программировании, где важна каждая запятая, видеолекции культивируют дилетантизм.

Comment: @gbg, так с книгами ещё меньше обратной связи. В комментариях под курсами ведь можно оставить комментарий в случае, если что-то непонятно. Подозреваю, что авторам книг пишут поменьше.

Comment: во время "живой лекции с обратной связью" можно поймать автора тепленьким - прямо в момент объяснения. Все попытки общения с автором постфактум будут мене продуктивны, так как к этому моменту, автор лекции просто забудет, что он конкретно говорил и зачем.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, домохозяйки, не имеющие способности к усидчивости (не способные прочитать книгу) не станут программистами. А школьников в программировании итак больше чем нужно

Comment: @СашаЧерных, к тому же, я не встречал видеоуроков, которые были бы (хотя бы) сравнимы с качественной литературой. В большинстве своем, видеоуроки - редкостный шлак, прививающий дурные привычки неокрепшим умом школьникам

Comment: @gbg, опять на мнениях аргумент, трудно возразить. Считаю иначе: да, автор помнит не столько, как во время самого видеокурса, но он специалист (другие варианты не рассматриваем), часто сталкивается с предметом курса, и на большинство вопросов сможет ответить.

Comment: IMHO. Если отбросить всякий шлак уровня "посмотрели? теперь купите/запишитесь", то вменяемых видеокурсов останется не так уж и много. Пример: https://youtu.be/gMqezSMp38U Но это рассчитано на определённый уровень аудитории. Все остальные видеокурсы не просто не полезны, а вредны, так как (если не развивать подробности) не способствуют развитию самостоятельного мышления.

Comment: @PinkTux Даже этот видеоурок — какая-то муть: описания нет, списка необходимых знаниий нет, куча воды, звук ужасный, всё плохо. Если переводить в категорию текстовых обучающих материалов, то это получится не книга, а запись "я тут замутил клёвую фигню" в малоизвестном блоге узкого специалиста, в которой информация перемежается байками о жизни, и котороая написана бледным светлосерым по белому. Тем, кто в теме — будет интересно. Но это не материал, который я могу рекомендовать для обучения.

Comment: `Даже этот видеоурок — какая-то муть`, `Тем, кто в теме — будет интересно`, `это не материал, который я могу рекомендовать для обучения` - разве в моих словах был какой-то другой смысл?

Comment: @PinkTux  > то вменяемых видеокурсов останется не так уж и много. — вот их и добавлять. Книгами на русскоязычном Stack Overflow ведь заправляют небольшое количество высокореповых участников, и с курсами то же самое.

Comment: > Если на хостинге они станут недоступны — А действительно ли хорошие видеокурсы столь часто оказываются недоступными? Есть какая-нибудь статистика или хотя бы личный опыт обращения с ними? Авторы наверняка изо всех сил стараются сохранить курсы и, соответственно, аудиторию. // Притом ничего не мешает скачать видео и выложить на торрент-трекер, как и делается.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, приведите пример вменяемого видеокурса. Который бы не развивал навык "делай как я", то есть программирование методом Copy+Paste :)

Comment: @PinkTux, Вы же и привели.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, это был скорей антипример. Я ж не зря написал, что он рассчитан на определённую аудиторию. Вот сразу же, здесь, и нашёлся человек, который в неё не попал :) Но если речь о курсах для новичков, то не вижу большой разницы между "видеокурсами" и книжками "X за Y времени для чайников".

Answer (score 3):

## Списки видеокурсов нужны. Но не любых.

Видеокурсов очень много и их снимают все кому не лень. Из-за этого качество часто бывает весьма сомнительное. Однако, видеокурсы весьма удобны для обучения, поскольку позволяют полностью увидеть, как надо делать то, что тебя интересует. Как же выбрать те, которые действительно полезны и которые стоит посмотреть? Вот тут-то и пригодятся рекомендации видеокурсов.

#### В каком случае следует включать видеокурс в список?

Если ты лично посмотрел курс, разбираешься в его тематике и уверен, что он хороший.

#### Как обеспечить наличие в списке только хороших видеокурсов?

Добавляющий курс в список должен под ним написать краткое описание и характеристику, указав свой ник. Т. е. добавляя курс, ты лично даёшь гарантию, что он хороший и его стоит посмотреть. При желании, несколько других участников могут добавить отзывов.

#### Пример

**Скринкаст NODE.JS - Илья Кантор**

- http://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/nodejs
- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDyvV36pndZFWfEQpNixIHVvp191Hb3Gg

> **[Qwertiy](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy):** Замечательный курс по основам node.js. Первая часть покрывает основы и позволяет изучить node.js c нуля. Вторая показывает работу с вебсокетами и express — весьма распространённым модулем для веб-приложений. К сожалению, описывает уже устаревшую версию node.js, но описываемые основы по-прежнему актуальны.

---

PS: Чтобы разместить две цитаты подряд, надо поставить между ними на отдельной строке комментарий `<!-- -->`.

Comment: Не озвучены критерии качества видео: по сути предлагается заменить критерии личным поручательством "мамой клянусь -- хороший курс". Даже простое "видео набрало более миллиона просмотров/лайков" -- это критерий. Кроме того, кто-то ведь должен тратить время, чтобы отсмотреть эти часы видео -- я бы предложил просто за попытку добавления  видео списывать пятьсот баллов кармы (и возвращать шестьсот при утверждении ссылки). Чтобы не заставляли просматривать весь этот видеоспам. И в пояснении обязательно нужно писать "Замечательный курс. Без рекламы и СМС". ;)

Comment: @AK, на спам есть критерий и управа. Для меня вполне достаточно, что участник с достаточно хорошей репутацией советует мне некий материал. Я смотрю видеокурсы, когда хочу узнать определённые темы. Полагаю, другие тоже смотрят. Вот у тебя репутация 1203 сейчас. Ты станешь давать ссылку на какой-то абсолютно левый курс? Вряд ли. Если сделать формат не общего ответа, а личных, то можно будет ставить не только минусы, но и влепить тревогу за спам. Если она подтвердится, пользователь получит минус 100. Ну и доверие к другим его подобным ответам окажется соответствующее.

Answer (score 0):

Какие то вы странные, есть курсы с фундаментальными знаниями. Например курс гарварда по основам программирования. Они универсальны и описывают базовые принципы современных ит технологий.

[На русском](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLawfWYMUziZqyUL5QDLVbe3j5BKWj42E5)

Считаю не правильно не рассказывать об этом новичкам.

Comment: Допустим. А ещё какие? Желательно при этом на русском.

Comment: Не мало , уж поверьте. [алгоритмы](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLY7PmJJFH5nSkAteyHnYQzi0FY4JniexT). Много талантливых парней, [по вёрстке](https://www.youtube.com/user/agragregra/videos) , [по администрированию виндовс сервера](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfxkzoy71UExMrABlmlecLQ/playlists), [по игровой разработке](https://www.youtube.com/user/SkanerSoft/playlists) . [Яндекс доступно объясняет современные ит технологии](https://events.yandex.ru/). @VladD , объясни что я упускаю?

Comment: Вы упускаете то, что приведённые вами видео ужасны. Я потратил 11 минут на то, чтобы посмотреть видео про пузырьковую сортировку. Автор видео не сумел даже внятно доказать, что на второй итерации второй по величине элемент попадёт в финальную позицию. Он вообще не затронул вопрос асимптотической сложности (не говоря уж о реально сложных вопросах о минимуме-максимуме-дисперсии-противодействии атакам). Уровень изложения рассчитан на детский садик. Такого качества видео забито пол-интернета. И вы хотите, чтобы мы рекомендовали конкретно этого автора, а не миллион других настолько же плохих?

Comment: Хочется согласиться с вами, но что то останавливает меня. Послушайте, если интересны такие подробности, можно рекомендовать [спец. курс мгу](http://course.secsem.ru/). Через садик тоже нужно пройти, нельзя сразу охватить всю тему. А списки фундаментальных видео-курсов, были бы полезны я считаю.

Comment: @stas0k Первые 5 минут https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keg9wuOlX-o - учимся копипастить огромные куски разметки? Какие-то шаблоны, мастер-страницы или хотя бы инклюды? Не, просто копипаст. Стили в heders.sass чтобы быстрее всего применялись? Быстрее всего? Что?? И вообще, файлик для стилей страницы, не? isnohome? o_O. В общем, бррррр... А давай-ка по моему [варианту](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3478/178988): чем именно тебе помогли эти курсы по вёрстке?

Comment: Но позвольте, мой главный критерий по оценке рекомендуемого курса. Необходимо чтобы он охватывал всю тему и не оставлял белых пятен. В пример я приводил курс гарварда по основам программирования cs 50, который перевели на русский. 


На рекомендуемом мной канале по вёрстке, можно посмотреть как сверстать из макета готовый внешний вид сайта, от начала и до конца. У человека реальный опыт и он с ним делиться. Почему вы хотите запретить ссылаться на опытных людей, которые делятся своим опытом, в современное время, зачастую через ютуб и другие видеосервисы ?

Comment: @stas0k, напротив. проблема в том, что я профессионализма как раз не увидел. А про гарвардский курс вроде никто и не спорил. Хотя я туда не заглядывал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, благодарю. видимо критерий отбора не достижим, на данном ресурсе

Answer (score -3):

Да, нужны.

- **Такой формат имеет максимум возможностей по наглядной демонстрации предмета** без участия слушателя.
- **У нас уже есть курируемые сообществом списки литературы.** А видеокурсы отличаются от них только формой информации. Они точно так же последовательно подают информацию, если их смотреть подряд. Книгу тоже можно читать в любой угодной читателю последовательности, но виноват в неусвоении материала будет в итоге читатель, а не носитель материала.
- ...

Comment: Выглядит это так, будто аргументов "за" попросту нет. Может быть, сами что-то добавите?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, полчаса назад вопрос всего задан.

Comment: @СашаЧерных а Вы добавте свои аргументы, почему Вы считаете что ссылки на видеокурсы действительно необходимы

Comment: @Bald, у меня тут нет авторитета, чтобы убеждать сообщество. Наверное, больше меня на Мете никого не минусили. А вдруг условный Discord займёт позицию, отличную от большинства.

Comment: @СашаЧерных дело не в авторитете и не в убеждении. оформите вразумительно критерии почему как Вы считаете видеокурсы действительно необходимы. почему сообщество должно взвалить на себе: *«отделять зёрна от плевел»*

Comment: @СашаЧерных у вас достаточно много заплюсованных вопросов. Минусы здесь связаны не с личным отношением к вам, а с тем, что этот вариант 1) не аргументирован 2) не поддерживается многими участниками.

Comment: @Bald, так сообщество взваливает на себя: *«отделение зёрен от плевел»* в отношении книг. Ваш аргумент про различие количества курсов и книг понял, спасибо.

Comment: Добавил аргумент, который слышу чаще всего в разных формах.

Comment: @D-side, это аргумент о плюсах и минусах самих видеокурсов как класса. А нужны аргументы о необходимости или нет их наличия в соответствующих ответах на ru SO.

Comment: @СашаЧерных это подмножество последних. А условиях полного отсутствия аргументов это хоть что-то.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Условный Сквидвард выскажется за уроки, если он увидит список уроков, которые достойны упоминания. Впрочем, [Сквидвард высказывался даже против списков книг](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/165), и с тех пор его мнение мало изменилось.

Comment: @Squidward это Дискорд высказывался против, а Сквидвард ничего такого не говорил про списки.