# Что делать с вопросами про учебные материалы?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, учебные-материалы

Просматривая, изучая и редактируя различные вопросы на SO, я много раз натыкаюсь на самую актуальную тему для начинающих разработчиков/программистов, это учебные материалы. Заметил, что далеко не многие более опытные коллеги желают подсказать. Очень часто, некоторые люди, даже как-то негативно реагируют на данные вопросы, я и сам так делал по-началу, каюсь.
Конечно хорошо, что уже есть на SO вопросы связанные с этой тематикой и их достаточно много, но если, эти самые вопросы, проскакивают через сита модерации буквально через день/два, то тут начинают возникать вопросы наподобие.

Что не так, или почему они летят к нам минуя Google?

Возможно (я лишь предполагаю), для русскоязычного человека `ru.stackoverflow` является чем-то большим и сообщество обязано более серьезно рассмотреть данный вопрос?

Что мы можем сделать лучше, чтоб пользователь получал максимально качественную информацию из сообщества, а не в расстроенных чувствах покидал данный ресурс с мыслью: и тут то же самое?

Мы же не просто так называемся **сообщество**? Давайте сообща придумаем, как мы можем обогатить наш ресурс новыми материалами, **учитывая авторские права** само собой.

Знаю, что уже поднимались вопросы [про видеокурсы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3413/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2), [про поиск библиотек/плагинов/инструментов/приложений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2615/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9), а также вопросы [в стиле “скажите что почитать”](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/162#162) и многие другие, но пока что все так как есть.

Первая мысль, которая мне приходит постоянно в голову, так это то, что теги связанные с учебными материалами, такие как [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8) и им подобные, подсвечивать иным цветом и если есть такая возможность, оповещать всех новых пользователей о том, что на ресурсе имеется достаточное количество рекомендаций о всевозможной литературе и данные вопросы не стоит задавать, а лишь дополнять имеющиеся, если человек готов поделиться чем-то более актуальным на данный момент.

Поделитесь пожалуйста своим мнением, идеями / рекомендациями.

Как поступать в ситуациях с такими вопросами?

Comment: Некоторая качественная литература , часто предоставляется бесплатно (при этом `не нарушаются авторские права`). Приведу пример такой компании как [O'Reilly](https://www.oreilly.com/), думаю многие частенько сталкиваются с их изданиями. Раз в какой-то период они дают возможность выкачивать различную литературу в высоком качестве (разные форматы). Да литература на английском языке, но все же, она есть и самое главное бесплатно. Возможно кто-то еще сталкивался с чем-то подобным...

Comment: *`"Что не так, или почему они летят к нам минуя Google?"`* -- мне кажется, что люди, задающие вопрос о том, что почитать, ждут не только ссылок, но (и это главное) личных комментариев к ссылкам и возможного дальнейшего диалога с отвечающими. Вот это главное, что им надо, а нагуглить ссылки не проблема. Проблема понять, какой материал стоит читать, а на какой можно время не тратить.

Comment: Для начала перестать "каяться" в том что не является "грехом". Вопросы по поиску литературы не несут абсолютно никакой ценности, с чего относиться к ним положительно?

Comment: 1- google является UI для большинства читателей Stack Overflow (90+% трафика). То есть Stack Overflow это место куда google направляет (как и задумано) 2- есть канонические вопросы с меткой [книги]. Чтобы *спам* по всему сайту не ловить, можно там все полезные ссылки аккумулировать. Новые вопросы либо как дубликаты закрывать (если они полезны для SEO) либо как too subjective закрывать. Если существующего канонического вопроса нет, то на Мету направлять (чтобы решение принять нужен новый такой вопрос, добавив тему при необходимости [к общему списку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/23044))

Comment: в тему: почему на Stack Overflow вредно без ограничений общаться на произвольные темы как это делается на обычных форумах [How do I respond to assertions that Stack Overflow is just like a forum?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362473/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Закрывать как дискуссионный.

#### Или, если есть подходящий дубликат с меткой [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8) — дубликатить.

На Stack Overflow (большом) такие вопросы оффтопик настолько, что для этого есть отдельная причина: "вопросы с просьбами порекомендовать книгу, бибилиотеку или иной ресурс извне сайта".

Почему у нас? Ну хотя бы потому, что так сказано [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> #### Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать:
>
> - Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию. Для списков литературы выделены особые поддерживаемые сообществом вопросы. Вместо того, чтобы задавать новый вопрос, найдите уже существующий в [вопросе-указателе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/). Также список литературы и других ресурсов часто можно найти в описаниях меток по соответствующим темам.

Но справка всего лишь *собрание выводов*. Но важно понимать и выводов *из чего*.

---

Почему люди задают такие вопросы на SO? Потому что вопросы связаны с ИТ, разумеется.

Понаблюдайте за лентой какое-то время, и увидите, что с завидной регулярностью появляются даже вопросы о том, что Майнкрафт не запустился.

---

Ввиду большого потока запросов на учебные материалы [мы решили (как вы уже заметили)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/162/181100) заклеить проблему синей изолентой: допускать такие вопросы исключительно в форме *канонических*. С единственным общим ответом, чтобы избежать субъективности на корню, фактически избавившись от голосования за индивидуальные источники.

**Важное уточнение:** канонические вопросы должны откуда-то появляться, верно? Важное условие: в сообществе в первую очередь должны быть *опытные участники*, что займутся начальным наполнением и дальнейшей поддержкой вопроса по некоторой теме. То, что такие вопросы *реально задаются*, к сожалению, должно отойти на второй план.

Запрещены у нас такие вопросы потому, что к ним не представляется возможным эффективное применение почти всех тех инструментов, что нам доступны на этой платформе.

Как уже отмечено выше, голосования намеренно устранены. Посему, вклад в такие вопросы не измеряется очками репутации, конкурсы невозможны, галочка не имеет смысла (ответ-то один), количество приложенных усилий из истории видно плохо, закрывать эти вопросы нельзя ([попытки были](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-javascript#comment661131_474385)).

Остаются правки, версионирование и обсуждение.
Функциональность вики, в общем.
Но кроме этого неплохо бы:

- пособирать информативные отзывы по отдельным источникам от разных участников с регалиями, отвечающими на вопрос "какое вы право имеете критиковать"
- поотмечать отдельные источники метками (разбить их на непересекающиеся множества практически нереально)
- некоторые источники добавить в несколько списков сразу
- предлагать на обсуждение новые источники (и не показывать в списке до подтверждения другими участниками) или удаление существующих с уведомлением потенциального "жюри", чтобы ускорить обсуждение

  - для участников с 2000+ репы предлагаемые правки недоступны, несколько предлагаемых правок сразу к одному вопросу существовать не могут
  - чат — так себе решение, за ним нужно наблюдать, или собирать где-то в чате закреплённые списки участников, которых надо бы уведомить; причём если кто-то из них в чате давно не был, что запросто, их всё равно уведомить не получится!

*(если у меня опять разгуляется воображение в этом направлении, список дополню)*

Всех этих инструментов не было и нет на SO, и в обозримом будущем они вряд ли появятся, потому что SO не для этих целей существует. А строить сложные общественные инициативы с помощью внешних инструментов вроде чата бессмысленно из-за их сложности и натянутости на инструменты — будет мало участников, слабое обсуждение, и как следствие низкое качество результатов.

**Можно написать отдельное веб-приложение/сайт**, в котором реализовать достойный инструментарий для этих целей. Можно даже сделать авторизацию через Stack Exchange, чтобы людям не пришлось заводить новых аккаунтов, а у них можно было подсмотреть рейтинги по меткам и уровень репутации (можно просто показывать как подкрепление отзыва, можно ограничивать доступ для вклада). А заодно и список меток с актуальной информацией о них, чтобы создать иллюзию, что это те же самые метки.

Такой формат, конечно, тоже не даёт никаких бонусов очками репутации на самом SE. Но в нём можно хотя бы сделать собственную, что тоже неплохо.

Но чтобы это сделать, кому-то нужно потратить время. Есть желающие? :)

Comment: мне было бы интересно поучаствовать в таком проекте, но только если на *подхвате*, так как силенок не хватит

Comment: Может, для этих целе сделать отделный сайт сети Stack Exchange?
P.S.: это идея, мне самому лень :D

Comment: @val это задача, сопоставимая с разработкой нового движка (или раздела, вроде Документации на SO). Потому что нынешний движок для этих целей не подходит вот совсем, и я объяснил в ответе, почему. И если такой эксперимент проводить и будут, то на большом SO. Практика показала, что ради нашего сообщества компания напрягается относительно несильно :)

Answer (score 1):

## Не согласен с тем, что такие вопросы нужно закрывать

В нашей базе знаний имеется специальный вопрос [книги и материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/3380). Если появляется новый вопрос с просьбой порекомендовать литературу по теме, которая уже существует в специальном вопросе, то нужно помечать новый вопрос как дубликат. Если же это абсолютно новый вопрос, то на него можно дать общий ответ и внести его в вопрос-указатель. Например, туда можно было бы добавить вопрос по [сетевым технологиям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/326155/3380). Ответы объединить в один и сделать общим.

Comment: Не вполне согласен и добавил в связи с этим уточнение ([ревизия 3](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6805/revisions)). Чтобы вопрос имел смысл как канонический, для него нужен исключительно качественный ответ. Чтобы предоставить такой ответ, нужны участники, которые разбираются в теме и готовы уделить время. Если присмотреться к метке [tag:книги], авторы у вопроса и ответа самых популярных списков часто совпадают, именно по этой причине -- что инициатива исходила не от случайного прохожего, а от того, кто вызвался создать список. Вот.

Comment: Ну, то есть, никто не мешает лично вам, например, взять инициативу и подготовить вопрос по сетевым технологиям в принятом сообществом формате (из авторов, названий, ISBN, без обложек), а не как то, на что вы дали ссылку :) Можно и существующий вопрос преобразовать, попросив помощи у модераторов (сделать вопрос общим, поудалять прочие ответы).

Comment: Закрытие вопроса дубликатом защищает его от удаления духом. Желательно бы просто кидать автору ссылку, а закрывать вопрос как "не по теме", чтобы не захламлять сайт бесмысленными вопросами.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight можно и голосованием поудалять, если будут мешать. По-моему, они не особенно мешают.