# Выделить отдельные темы для учебной литературы в формате видео

Tags: обсуждение, учебные-материалы

На сайте есть специально выделенные темы под учебную литературу, где в формате общего ответа перечисляются книги, реже - сайты.

Я вижу противоречие в сложившейся практике: значительная часть сообщества [не хочет видеть в этих темах ссылки на видео](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3413/213987), но не менее заметная часть сообщества хочет учебные материалы именно в формате видео и только в нём.

Я сам из числа тех, кто предпочитает книги, но мне не очень нравится ситуация, когда на сайте появляются темы, в которых авторы просят ссылки на видео, эти темы закрываются (неформат для сайта), часто предлагается закрыть дубликатом на литературу.

Этот конфликт тлеет постоянно и я даже не знаю, что будет лучше: когда один из недовольных дойдёт до меты (пока никто не доходил, все удовлетворялись ответом "тут у нас правила такие" и никто не догадался, что правила можно поменять) или что люди просто будут уходить в негативе и будут переставать пользоваться сайтом.

Я выношу на обсуждение следующее предложение: давайте узаконим отдельные топики в формате видео. Ну будет у нас две отдельные темы, кому какой формат больше понравится - тот такой и выберет.

Предлагаю два основных варианта, проголосуйте "за" или "против":

- давайте сделаем отдельные темы для видео
- давайте оставим как есть: собираем только книги, видео закрываем как оффтопик для сайта

Если кому-то хочется высказаться отдельно - прошу на трибунку, пишите отдельный ответы.

Я не рассматриваю тему как повод для немедленного действия, скорее как опрос мнения активной части сообщества, эдакий термометр, поэтому в метках пока нет "предложение", только "обсуждение".

Comment: Проблема в том что уже в списки материалов добавляют видео. То есть решение на мете не работает.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, нужно их просто убрать из списков

Comment: Коллеги, давайте попробуем избежать модели голосовалок. Если кому–то есть что сказать по теме, пусть он или она опубликует развернутые мысли по теме. Пожалуйста, не публикуйте ответы из одного предложения–высказывания, подразумевающие лишь голос за или против. Такие ответы не вносят какой–либо новой информации о рассматриваемом вопросе и не помогут нам принять правильное обоснованное решение.

Answer (score 7):

## А давайте впишем в имеющееся!

Коротко, предлагаю:

- создать [учебные-материалы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b) и присинонимизировать к ней [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8), т. к. мы уже явно имеем дело не только с книгами, но с учебными материалами в целом
- разрешить добавление в общие спискоответы (в т. ч. уже существующие) видеоисточников; не вижу смысла размещать видео в отдельных ответах, т. к. структура у них наверняка будет схожей
- для удобства читателей установить необходимость помечать видео *в начале строки* значком  (кинокамерой) и отразить это а описании метки

---

Видеоуроки я тоже не люблю, уж очень вопиюще низкое у них качество в общей массе. Низкое настолько, что я даже не уверен, что сообщество сможет "отделить зёрна от плевел". Может остро встать вопрос фильтрации.

Но в общем случае я не считаю, что стоит запрещать весь формат только потому, что в нём много некачественного контента. Демонстрационных возможностей и наглядности у видео определённо больше, а значит подготовить учебные материалы в видеоформате эффективнее книг вполне себе возможно.

Думая о будущем — возможно, низкая планка качества связана как раз с тем, что мало кто занимается публичной оценкой и сбором стоящих источников. Поэтому ведение здесь списков может положительно повлиять на уровень создаваемых в будущем материалов.

К том же, обучающие видеоматериалы не ограничиваются видеоуроками. Я регулярно смотрю **записи докладов/презентаций с конференций**, в которых *как правило* качественный материал.

Так что...

**Давайте разрешим.** Когда возникнет проблема большого количества низкокачественных уроков в списках, тогда и будем её решать, а пока пользы от заведения списков видеоматериалов будет с виду больше, чем вреда.

А чтобы те, кого видео не интересует, могли при беглом просмотре их с лёгкостью пропускать; а те, кто ищет именно видеоуроки, цеплялись глазами именно за такие значки — предлагаю в обязательном порядке помечать видеоисточники в начале строки с помощью эмодзи .

---

#### *PS:*

*Открыв этот вопрос с системы на базе Linux, я увидел вместо восхитительного фигуристого цветного (ну, оттенки серого тоже цвета) значка камеры банальный и скучный **голый прямоугольничек**. Как и многие другие вещи в Linux, оказалось, что это проблема отсутствия эмодзи-шрифта и настроек, и чинится всё это буквально за пару минут, ещё и выбрать сорт эмодзи позволяет.*

*Так что не считаю это поводом отказываться от эмодзи как средства расширения структуры сообщений. В конце концов, 2018 год на дворе.*

Answer (score 6):

Я за видео. Хоть сам их очень мало смотрел за всю жизнь, в основном на книги налегал.

Противники видео часто пишут, что снять его может любой манки-кодер. Но ведь и статейку в бложик тиснуть так же просто или ответ на форуме. Такие любительские видео нужно сравнивать не с книгами, а с блог-постами и сообщениями на форумах.

Аналогом книг нужно считать видео, снятые профессионально. Например, профессор читает курс лекций в ВУЗе. Это снимают на видео и выкладывают для всеобщего доступа. Такое видео по качеству информации ничуть не хуже книг.

---

От себя ещё добавлю, что у многих айтишников проблемы со зрением. Чтобы читать книги, нужно напрягать глаза. Когда используешь мультимедиа, то основной поток информации идёт через уши - речь лектора. А глазами лишь изредка посматриваешь на экран, они отдыхают. Конечно, зависит от преподаваемого материала.

Comment: Хм, а вопрос-то про книги, а не статейки. Их же не вставляют в список (возможно как исключение). Видео с профессорами я смотрел, это жуть: пожилой дядя, бубня себе под нос что-то, пишет на доске, не зная про захват экрана. А про зрение, уши соглашусь. Но только при наличии хорошего материала, который иногда находишь в коротких роликах. Вот для таких, возможно, можно выделить тему.

Answer (score 6):

Я тоже сторонник книг. Считаю, что в большинстве случаев то, что можно найти и прочесть в книге за 5-10 минут, необходимо смотреть в условном ролике 40 тех же минут, а то и больше. Очень часто в различных видео-материалах, автора начинают давать информацию никак не относящуюся к вопросу, который они вынесли на обзор публики, рассказывают о их предпочтениях в стилизации консоли или редактора и т.д.

Но, игнорировать видео в целом, тоже глупо. Мы все-таки вошли в цифровую эру, а видео, это один из источников информации и способов обучения, существует большое количество людей которые видео-контент воспринимают куда-более быстрее.
У меня мысль такая давно в голове засела, что с этим делать и как-то даже [поднимал схожий вопрос о учебных материалах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6803/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b) и частично касался вопроса видео.

Я поддерживаю инициативу автора о расширении направления учебных материалов и создания отдельной метки для этого, такой как [учебные-материалы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b) или [видео-материалы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b). Название это уже отдельный вопрос, который надо вынести на голосование.
Варианту с [вписаться в имеющиеся](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7125/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be/7131#7131) также симпатизирую (думаю он более компромиссный).

Да, я понимаю тех, кто переживает что все превратиться в балаган и пользователи будут добавлять все в подряд (включая спам). Думаю в процессе, сообщество отфильтрует все ненужное / некачественное и в результате будет лучшая подборка обучающих видео-материалов в русскоязычном пространстве. Ведь если подумать, нет пока такого идеального ресурса, где такая информация есть. Так почему бы не быть первыми? Давайте станем эталоном качества. Кто нам это запрещает реализовать? Все в наших руках коллеги.

Answer (score 2):

Выскажусь против.

Книги - вещь, которую сложно сделать, нужно много труда, времени, зачастую и денег для выпуска релиза. Как следствие, качество в таком труде будет как минимум пригодное (не в счёт всякую популярную литературу, пишущую то, что хочет народ, а не донося знания).
Видео - вещь, которая благодаря ютьюбу и распространённости смартфотов с камерой может быть создана практически любой обезьяной с палкой для сэлфи (хм...). И контент соответствующий.

Плюс в контексте объёма доносящего формата, книга с сотней страниц никого не удивит, а видео на сотню часов уже да.

Как итог:
В книгах иногда можно найти некачественный продукт, в видео же - иногда найти качественный.
Копаться никто не хочет.

---

Можно лишь создать аналог книжного репо на мете, только с видео, если уж совсем есть хороший видеоконтент.
Однако, книгу можно найти по ISBN, а видео как искать? Ссылка протухнуть может.

Comment: Прямо говоря, я ничего нового не услышал: всё это уже обсуждалось в [связанной теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3413/213987). Однако поскольку Николас в последнее время поощряет высказываться, а не просто голосовать - выскажу своё мнение голосом "за". Давайте только не забывать и на остальных ответах оставлять свои голоса.

Comment: @AK, отлично! Только непонятно тогда зачем Вы создали тему с опросом. Мнение тех, кто знает что мета вообще существует (т. е. более-менее активные), Вы знаете, остальное мнение мы не услышим, поэтому получим [ошибку выжившего](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0).

Comment: Я постоянно ищу потенциальные точки роста для аудитории сайта. Даром предвидения не обладаю, угадать, какое предложение вызовет больше негатива или меньше - не могу. Но я могу словами спросить, послушать мнение, посмотреть реакцию. Я знаю, что почему-то есть стойкая корреляция между тем, что человек быстрее набирает опыт из книг, а не видео, но понимаю, что отваливание новичков происходит именно на ранних этапах, а там почему-то любят видео. Возможно ли чуть подвинуться в сторону менее опытных или стоит целенаправленно поддерживать быстрый рост знаний за счёт обрубания неэффективного? Не знаю.

Comment: Именно поэтому список качественного среди кучи всего и нужнее, чем список качественного среди качественного.

Comment: @Other, какую ещё ошибку выжившего? Если кто-то не знает, что мета существует, то ему всё равно, какие тут правила.

Comment: @Qwertiy, но он же пользуется этими правилами, хочет он или нет, т. е. попадает под их действие. И я говорил о принятии решения, а не о простых пользователях.

Answer (score 2):

За то, чтобы список видеокурсов (уроков?) выделять в отдельные ответы.

---

Как и в случае с литературой подобный список не будет являться рекомендацией в виде: видеокурсы от А отличные, а вот B никуда не годятся. Это сбор информации в удобном виде, а что именно выбрать каждый уже решит сам.

Я сам не являюсь сторонником обучающих видео, но если многие находят такой формат полезным, то зачем им запрещать делиться информацией? Зачем навязывать свою точку зрения окружающим?

Comment: Эм.. С одной стороны, информация, что курс никуда не годится, полезна, с другой - что-то мне бы не хотелось списки плохих курсов.

Answer (score 0):

> Давайте узаконим отдельные темы для видео.

Обоснование: Stackoverflow - сеть знаний и знания в формате видео тоже кому-то нужны.

Правила будут такие же как и для литературы в формате книг: оставляем один вопрос для одной темы, остальное закрываем дубликатами на выделенный вопрос, пополняя его.

Возможно, стоит в вопросе про книги давать ссылку на видео, а в вопросах с видео - ссылку на книги, но это уже детали реализации (не главное в этом предложении).

Foggy Finder и Nofate упоминали:

> Проблема в том что уже в списки материалов добавляют видео.

Думаю, что если под видео будут выделены отдельные темы – то эта волна добавлений прекратится и можно будет поудалять оттуда видео в их отдельные темы.

Comment: Поудалять их можно и сейчас, так как они противоречат принятому решению. Разместившим - сделать внушение.